# Confusion about node.js internal asynchronous I/O mechanism

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, io, libuv

1. I have learned that node.js use libeio internally to perform async **file** I/O, with thread pool, on *nix platform, am I right?
2. What about async **network** I/O? Is it done by libev? Is there also a thread pool?
3. If there is thread pool inside, how could it be more efficient than traditional one-thread-per-request model? And is it one thread per I/O request?
4. And what's the mechanism on windows? I know it's done by IOCP, and there's a kernel level thread pool, right?
5. Why linux doesn't have a native completely AIO mechanism like windows IOCP yet? Will it have in future?

Update according to changchang's answer:

1. I took a quick view at the [source code](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/780c08a63efb65aed65da57c36f1c5b10f25cc1d/src/threadpool.c) @changchang have given, found that the default thread pool size can be reset by **UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE**, I'm wondering in which case this will be used?
2. I also found getaddrinfo use this thread pool, is there any more except fs? And if all sync jobs will be done in this thread pool, is the default size '4' enough?
3. As my understanding now, there will be 6 basic threads in node.js process: 1 V8 thread(event loop, where user javascript codes runs), 1 libuv event loop, and 4 in thread pool, am I right?
4. And how can I see these threads in my shell(Ubuntu)? I use **ps -eLf | grep node | grep -v grep** only saw two:

   root     16148  7492 16148  0    2 20:43 pts/26   00:00:00 ./bin/node /home/aaron/workspace/test.js
   root     16148  7492 16149  0    2 20:43 pts/26   00:00:00 ./bin/node /home/aaron/workspace/test.js

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680601/nodejs-event-loop

Comment: node.js actually uses [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/) to abstract asynchronous IO for all supported platforms

Comment: @user568109 I have read that, but cant't get straight answer from it, actually, unclear expression confuse me more. It mentioned that libeio 'perform input output asynchronously' including sockets, I doubt that. I learned this from somewhere that: because can't use epoll on regular files, so here comes libeio to perform aio with threads.

Comment: @simfoo Yeah, I know libuv, I'm wondering the mechanism under it, both *nix and windows.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. First of all, `libuv` has removed the `libeio` from it. But it does perform async file I/O with a thread pool like `libeio` just as you mentioned.
2. `libuv` also removes `libev`. It does the async network I/O based on the async I/O interfaces in different platforms, such as `epoll`, `kqueue` and `IOCP`, without a thread pool. There is a event loop which runs on the main thread of `uv` which polls the I/O events and processes them.
3. The thread pool inside `libuv` is a fixed size thread pool ([4 in uinx like system](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html)). It performs a task queue role and avoids the exhaustion of the system resources by generating threads indefinitely when the requests increase.

Comment: Tanks a lot, a lot resources out there is out of date, you just saved me!

Comment: @AaronWang you should accept this if it answered your question.

Comment: First: *libuv [...] does the async network I/O [...] **without a thread pool***. Later: *The thread pool inside libuv [...]*. It seems contradictory to me.

Comment: Isn't 4 a very small number, especially for io bound tasks. Does node allows to change the pool size?

Comment: ^ Yes it does, through UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE

Answer (score 2):

Uptil version 0.6 node used `libev` to run event-loop and `libeio` for asynchronous I/O, (Unix backend sits heavily on these two libraries). But `libuv` has started replacing `libev` and `libeio` in [version 0.8](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/06/25/node-v0-8-0/). It performs, mantains and manages all the io and events in the event pool. [`libuv`](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/09/23/libuv-status-report/) is the choice in cross-platform asynchronous IO libraries.

1. Yes, upto node 0.6, deprecated in 0.8 and uses thread pool
2. Yes, but `libev` does not use thread pool. See [here](http://nodejs.org/oscon.pdf)

   Clarification : According to the [link](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libeio/eio.pod) in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680601/nodejs-event-loop) I posted, `libeio` does support all POSIX functions dealing with I/O (which includes socket). But node author decided to use it for async file I/O only, and uses `libev` for network I/O. I dont know where you heard it from but you can use epoll on regular files.
3. `libev` uses event loop so no problems here.
4. Yes [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx) handles async I/O in windows, kernel does use thread pools.
5. New linux kernel has epoll, kqueue in new BSD kernel. `libev` and `libeio` were for linux environment and provides event loop/async IO for all kernel (supports select, poll, epoll, kqueue).

Update questions:

1. dont know much about `libuv`
2. maybe enough (dont know)
3. Here are my findings on Windows 8, checked it via Process Explorer. Showed 4 threads, 1 DLL, 1 File and 1 Section (total 7 entries) for a node application process.
4. `ps -eLf` does show all threads and processes, maybe you are over-filtering it, just look for the node process pid like `ps -eLf | grep x` where x is pid for node process.