# Writing an asynchronous method in Javascript (Code run in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the following code, I'm attempting to understand the concept of writing asynchronous JavaScript functions. To be clear on my assumptions:

The function logTest() is called. It calls asyncTest(), passing in the log() function. However, asyncTest() doesn't call log() directly. Rather, it passes it to the event queue to be called when the stack clears. The stack shouldn't clear until after the for loop completes, writing twenty "waiting..."'s. However, the console output puts the "async" line first before the for loop. I ran this code in Node.js, in which console.log is a synchronous function. Does anyone know why the "async" line wasn't written last?

```
function asyncCall(method) {
  return setTimeout(method, 0);
}

function log(str) { console.log(str); }

function logTest() {
  asyncCall(log("async"));
  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    log("waiting...");
  }
}

logTest();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js Event loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568613/node-js-event-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're passing *the result* of `log("async")` rather than the function `log` to `asyncCall`.

Basically, it executed `log("async")` (logging "async" to the console prior to executing `asyncCall`). The result of the call (which is `undefined` since `log` doesn't return anything) is passed to `asyncCall`. *Then* async call gets executed.

You may want to change that to:

```
asyncCall(log.bind(null, "async"))
```

or

```
asyncCall(function(){
  log("async");
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about asynchronous execution. He is expecting the 'async' string printed after the lines printed in the loop, which is not a correct assumption.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing in `log("async")` you are calling it and passing the result into `asyncCall()`

as soon as you add `()` you are (usually) calling a function. As Joseph mentioned, you can pass in either `log.bind(null, "async")` (although I prefer binding `this`), or you can pass in a new function that calls `log("async")` by doing something like:

```
asyncCall(function(){
  log("async");
});
```

However, to answer your real question, your assumption that "async" will be printed after 20 "waiting..." is incorrect.
In order to better understand the event queue, i suggest you read [this](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/)

basically, even though node is technically single threaded, it acts kind of like a multi-threaded application, so it can act as if it does many things at once.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @leo.fcx just realized you are right, will update my answer