# node.js - Is there a single event loop for the entire Node runtime?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

After reading this [post](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/28/node-is-not-single-threaded.aspx), it has given me the impression that Node starts its event loop only when I start a server, with the listen() method.

Is that true ?

**What happens if I start multiple servers on different ports ? Does that mean there are multiple event loops per server ?**

Also what happens if on one terminal I write-:

```
node server1.js
```

and on the second terminal I write

```
node server2.js
```

**How may node processes will be there and how many event loops will be running ?**

So does the event loop start up with the node.js runtime or is it specific to the starting of an app/server ?

Comment: Definitely take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568613/node-js-event-loop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644328/when-is-the-thread-pool-used

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am sorry but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. My question is that whether there is a single event loop for the entire Node runtime ? or is a loop started everytime I start a server. I guess that was not clear in my question so I have edited it.

Comment: Yes, there is a single loop per process. No, it starts regardless of your server, your app can do anything simpler than a server and you still have the loop there.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So, just correct me if I am wrong. If I write in one terminal `node server1.js` and open and another terminal and write `node server2.js` it will start another node process right ?

Comment: Yes, `node` is an OS app that, when invoked, starts a new process.