# How many threads does Node actually create?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, threadpool, libuv

After reading [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644735/2600208) about Node's thread nature,
I started to play with `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` system variable to change the size of thread pool, and I found something interesting:

When I set

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 10;
```

I get 15 threads in my Node process (I thought it should be 10 + 1 main Node thread = 11).

Have a look at my script:

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 10;

//init thread pool by calling `readFile` function
require('fs').readFile(__filename, 'utf8', function(err, content) {});

//make node not exiting
setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
```

After running it I type:

```
ps -Lef | grep test.js | grep -v grep
```

and get the following results:

```
olegssh   4869  4301  4869  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4870  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4871  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4872  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4873  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4874  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4875  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4876  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4877  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4878  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4879  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4880  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4881  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4882  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
olegssh   4869  4301  4883  0   15 16:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/olegssh/node/bin/node test.js
```

As you can see there are 15 threads running.

If I set `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1`, I get 6 threads.

If I comment out the `readFile` line (so the thread pool is not initialized), I get 5 threads.

So I make a conclusion that Node at startup creates 5 threads. Why not 1?

Can somebody shed some light on this?

**Edit:** I'm using brand new Node 4.0.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since node v6.0.0 you can define how many threads are used by V8 via the `--v8-pool-size` flag:

> --v8-pool-size=num
> Set V8's thread pool size which will be used to allocate background jobs.
> If set to 0 then V8 will choose an appropriate size of the thread pool based on the number of online processors.
> If the value provided is larger than V8's maximum, then the largest value will be chosen.

---

4 extra threads are [for use by V8](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/278a9267ec41f37e6b7dda876c417945d7725973/src/node.cc#L3964-L3965). V8 uses these threads to perform various tasks, such as GC-related background tasks and optimizing compiler tasks.

Comment: Wow, that is a very straight forward answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this architecture still same with latest Node (17)?