# Does Node.js support parallelism?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I've been looking more into the difference between concurrency and parallelism. I came upon a [talk on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso) given by Rob Pike speaking about the differences between concurrency and parallelism. His talk was in the context of the Google Go language. From what I understand, concurrency is the design of being able to handle multiple things, but parallelism is the physical execution of multiple things at the same time.

From what I also understand, Node.js runs as a single thread process. So although Node supports concurrency with the way it implements callbacks and such, does it have the ability to handle parallel execution of tasks? Can it be set up to run multiple threads on separate processors?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Node can support "Parallelism" via either the `Cluster` or `child_process` modules packaged in the Nodejs Core API. Both of these modules create additional processes and not additional threads.

Threads are created and managed, sometimes in a pool, "under-the-hood" by `libuv` which `node` implements and uses to perform the asynchronous operations such as reading from a file. **You cannot explicitly create a thread from your executing Javascript.** You can read more about `libuv` at the below resources

- [`libuv` API Docs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/index.html#)
- [`libuv` book](https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/index.html#)
- [Threading in `libuv`](https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html) (part of `libuv` book)

Also, this is great question on [Threads and Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22644328/2980607) which has a lot of detail.

`Cluster` is used distribute the workload of a Server across multiple cores and still have them share a port. However, `Cluster` uses `child_process.fork()` under the hood and communicates via [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). You can read more about [`Cluster` in the Nodejs Core API Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

[`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) offers a couple different ways to parallelize work via [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) or [`fork()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). The parent process can communicate with the child process using inter-process communication via pipes.

Basically, Node wants you to leverage [the event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and leave thread management to `libuv`. This is why it is so easy to build code that would typically require locking and thread safety measures. If you must do work that requires heavy lifting, or a significant amount of blocking (synchronous) work, then you could use `child_process` to offload that work. If you need to scale out a web app across cores then use `Cluster`.

Comment: I was under the impression that there was at least [one way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) to create multiple flows of execution that can run concurrently that communicate by passing messages to each other. Is that not so?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, no you are correct, that approach could use `child_process` and implement message passing with the `child_process.on('message')` event in the parent process and the `process.send()` function in the child process. I also wanted to limit my answer to what Node.js provides as part of its core functionality and not what packages could potentially provide.

Comment: @peteb Node 10.5.0 introduced Worker Threads into its core API (Jun 20, 2018). It would be great to update the answer to include that option as well!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for something along the lines of multithreading and/or computing multiple things at the same time.

**Multiple executions at once**
SIMD is beginning to find its way into Browsers, with Node implementations not far behind. Take a look at [node-simd](https://github.com/jonbrennecke/node-simd) or [MDN SIMD (browsers)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/SIMD_types). 
SIMD is still experimental, and only works on supported CPUs at the moment (obviously, since not all CPUs have this functionality). It executes multiple things at once, an example comparing normal JS to SIMD JS would be:

```
// Normal addition, 4 actions are executed.
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [5, 6, 7, 8];
var c = [];

c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
c[3] = a[3] + b[3];
c; // Array[6, 8, 10, 12]

// SIMD execution - all additions are processed simultaenously through the CPU
var a = SIMD.Float32x4(1, 2, 3, 4);
var b = SIMD.Float32x4(5, 6, 7, 8);
var c = SIMD.Float32x4.add(a,b);
c; // Float32x4[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

**Multithreading**
In regards to multithreading, `webworkers` have existed in the Browser environment for a while now. This has been ported to Node fully according to the HTML spec as seen [in this repository](https://github.com/pgriess/node-webworker).
Here's a [good explanation](http://blog.std.in/2010/07/08/nodejs-webworker-design/) as to why `webworkers` were even ported to Node in the first place, since you can already run child processes in other threads and on other CPUs with the `child_process` module. `node-webworker` is a great module since each process is run within its on context, and in its own `node` process, so it is truly multithreading with node.

So, to run different processes on different CPUs, you would either adopt `node-webworker` or use `child_process` to spawn other threads to do separate actions at the same time with different CPU cores. `node-webworker` can listen for events using the familiar `postMessage` API, and `child_process` will communicate through `stdin / stdout / stderr`.

Hope that answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple threads in separate processors on one host machine can be achieved by leveraging the native Node `os` and `cluster` modules. Following is a simple contrived example

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const os = require('os');

((port) => {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        // fork the process
        os.cpus().forEach((cpu) => {
            cluster.fork();
        });

    } else {
        // if we're not in the master thread, start the HTTP server
        http.createServer((req, res) => {
            // Handle request
        }).listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`The server is listening on port ${port}`);
        });
    }
})(3000)
```