# is nodejs slow while reading more than 4 big files at the same time?

Tags: node.js

I remember it seems that nodejs by default is using 4 back-end threads, therefore the fifth reading action will wait until 1 thread is available.

But I can't find any testify-example in google. Could someone explain and find the example please? Thanks.

Comment: Discussion of libuv thread pool used for disk I/O: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644328/when-is-the-thread-pool-used.  And, guess what, you can control how many threads there are.  One might also typically use clustering to involve more CPUs in scaling your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in [this post](https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/), as referred in the post from jfriend00. Thanks.