# linux command ab for benchmark on nodejs concurrent processes

Tags: node.js, apache

Option at ab linux command for benchmark is described at 
http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab,

-n number of request
-c number of concurrency

for example command to get statistic result on requesting index.html (file size=5937 bytes)

```
  ab -n 1000 -c 1000 http://localhost:8000/ and show the output as follows
```

My question is the command execute 1000 concurrent process  to get the index.html in 1000 times from one nodejs process at the same start time Right ? Why I need to specify -n 1000 ? How to describe the command with -n 1000 and -c 1000  together ? I believe -n option is set just for number of request re-try if previous request is failed for one process request. Right ?

```
    The command output on apache Centos
    ==================================
    Server Hostname:        localhost
    Server Port:            8000

    Document Path:          /
    Document Length:        5937 bytes

    Concurrency Level:      1000
    Time taken for tests:   0.725 seconds
    Complete requests:      1000
    Failed requests:        0
    Write errors:           0
    Total transferred:      6052000 bytes
    HTML transferred:       5937000 bytes
    Requests per second:    1378.45 [#/sec] (mean)
    Time per request:       725.455 [ms] (mean)
    Time per request:       0.725 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
    Transfer rate:          8146.83 [Kbytes/sec] received

    Connection Times (ms)
                min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
    Connect:        0   21  30.0      0      83
    Processing:    25  135  74.2     94     286
    Waiting:       24  135  74.2     93     286
    Total:         54  156  80.3    131     351

    Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
    50%    131
    66%    227
    75%    238
    80%    242
    90%    257
    95%    266
    98%    269
    99%    272
    100%    351 (longest request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-n` is how many requests to make in total. `-c` is how many requests to make simultaneously. If `-c` is less than `-n`, then not all the requests will be done at once. For example:

`-n 1000 -c 100` would immediately make 100 requests. When one request completes, another is started until 1000 requests have been sent.

Comment: so you mean 1000*1000 process request to start at the same time ?

Comment: what is different (-n 10 -c 1000) and (-n 1000 -c 1000) with same -c ?

Comment: No. Stop thinking simultaneous requests. `ab` doesn't always make all its requests simultaneously.

Comment: `-n 10` means only 10 requests are ever sent to the server.

Comment: So it just 1000 request ? why need to set -n ?

Comment: No, NOT 1000. `-n 10` makes TEN requests.

Comment: why not ab -n 1000 instead of ab -n 1000 -c 1000 ?

Comment: Because then `-c` would default to its default value, which is probably not 1000.

Comment: The question go to -c option, why need to set -c ?

Comment: To control how many are sent AT THE SAME TIME. You do understand time, right? That not everything happens at once? That things can be slowed down or delayed?

Comment: may be I know it concurrent level=2 (-c 2) and total request=10 (-n=10) that mean try to make total 10 request within 2 concurrent level that mean is depended how to apache to handle concurrent level

Comment: (-n 10 -c 2) it is same to use 2 process to request 10 request, one process to handle 5 request

Comment: it seems your question answer on post sounds correct

Comment: node.js uses non-blocking i/o, which means that usually a small, fixed number of processes handle all requests not matter how many. `ab` works the same way. One process is used to make all the requests using non-blocking i/o. For more information about this, check the documentation for `select` or `poll`. The overall behavior is as described above, however. `-c` requests are made simultaneously and `-n` requests are eventually sent.

Comment: it is good link to describe non-block I/O nodejs at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570246/what-is-non-blocking-or-asynchronous-i-o-in-node-js