# When to use blocking operations in node?

Tags: node.js, io, blocking, operation

For all i know, using non-blocking I/O operations is far better than blocking operations, once it makes use of callbacks (through polling)and the process can use the waiting time to serve other requests.

So, there is some real case where the advantage relies in using blocking I/O operations?

Comment: It is usefull at startup to load config, certs, ... But it doesnt make sense later for an server

Comment: I think your question is already discussed here->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570246/what-is-non-blocking-or-asynchronous-i-o-in-node-js