# What is difference between "Keras backend + Tensorflow" and "Keras from Tensorflow" using CPU(in Tensorflow 2.x)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2

I want to limit CPU cores and threads.
So I found three ways to limit these.

**1) "Keras backend + Tensorflow"**

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=2, \ 
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=4, \
                        allow_soft_placement=True, \
                        device_count = {'CPU': 1})
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

**2) "Keras from Tensorflow"**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(2)  
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(4)
```

**3) "keras from Tensorflow"**

```
import os

os.environ['TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS'] = '2'
os.environ['TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS'] = '4'
```

These three ways are same affects?

Lastly I understood for the parameters like I wrote below

- intra_op_parallelism_threads("number of CPU cores")
- inter_op_parallelism_threads("number of threads")

is this right?
If I miss-understanding please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, it's not as simple as that. As per official documentation -

**intra_op_parallelism_threads** - Certain operations like matrix multiplication and reductions can utilize parallel threads for speedups. A value of 0 means the system picks an appropriate number. [Refer this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_intra_op_parallelism_threads)

**inter_op_parallelism_threads** - Determines the number of parallel threads used by independent [non-blocking operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570246/what-is-non-blocking-or-asynchronous-i-o-in-node-js#:%7E:text=Blocking%20refers%20to%20operations%20that,it%20stalls%20execution%20to%20read.). 0 means the system picks an appropriate number. [Refer this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_inter_op_parallelism_threads)

*So technically you can not limit the number of CPUs but only the number of parallel [threads](https://www.guru99.com/cpu-core-multicore-thread.html#:%7E:text=CPU%20cores%20mean%20the%20actual,component%20which%20manages%20the%20tasks.&text=The%20CPU%20is%20fed%20tasks%20from%20a%20thread.), which, for the sake of limiting resource consumption, is sufficient.*

---

Regarding the methods, you are using -

The third approach allows you to directly set the environment variables using `os` library.

```
import os

os.environ['TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS'] = '2'
os.environ['TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS'] = '4'
```

The second approach is a method in tf2 that does exactly the same (sets environment variables), the difference being that Keras is packaged into tf2 now.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(2)  
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(4)
```

The first approach is for standalone Keras. This approach will work if keras is set to tensorflow backend. Again, it does the same thing which is set environment variables indirectly.

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=2, \ 
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=4, \
                        allow_soft_placement=True, \
                        device_count = {'CPU': 1})
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

If you still have doubts, you can check what happens to the environment variables after running all 3 independently and then check the specific variable using `os` with -

```
print(os.environ.get('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST'))
```

For a better understanding of the topic, you can [check this link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tips-to-improve-performance-for-popular-deep-learning-frameworks-on-multi-core-cpus.html) that details it out quite well.

---

**TLDR;** You can use the second or third approach if you are working with tf2. Else use the first or third approach if you are using standalone Keras with tensorflow backend.

Comment: Thank you so much details!
But still I'm not sure what number should I put.
I use TF2 and my computer cpu cores and logical processors both 8.

Comment: its actually quite difficult to say. The number of parallel threads depends on a lot of factors (your memory, language, etc). I would advise that if your goal is to limit resources, the start by setting the number of threads to a smaller number and analyzing the activity monitor or task manager.

Comment: Thank you. Still I'm not sure what is difference intra and inter means. I should find out by experiencing. And I printed os.environ.get('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST') out, It says None. If you don't mind could you tell me what 'None' means at 'KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST'?

Comment: "KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST" is a placeholder, you can change it to TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS or TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS

Answer (score 0):

For completing Akshay Sehgal answer, I found these facts regarding choosing the right number of intra and inter parallelism threads in my case by trial and error:

1. Almost all CPU logical cores (processors) correspond exactly to the number of intra parallelism threads (for example, if I reduce performance of a 8 logical processors CPU into 1 intra parallelism thread, then something around 1/8 of CPU performance will be exerted, however, the ratio is not exact). I also found that almost no role in changing CPU performance exists for inter parallelism threads after running my tensorflow model. However, I think it is best to specify number of inter parallelism threads as the rest of CPU's logical processors (for example, setting inter parallelism threads as 7 for a CPU with 8 logical processors when we already has chosen intra parallelism threads as 1) The reason is because I suspect inter parallelism threads might relate to the number of logical processors which runs other processes parellel to tensorflow model but I am not sure.
2. There are no difference between changing intra and inter parallelism threads in both os.enviorn AND tf.config method but for sake of safe execution I considered applying both methods.
3. Increasing threads more than number of your CPU's logical processors will keep its performance onto its maximum capacity for your process. for example, if your CPU has 8 logical cores, then defining 200 intra/inter parallelism threads is possible However the final performance still equals to 8 threads. Notice that in tensorflow calculations  CPU performance does not necessarily reach 100% if you assign maximum CPU performance for your model which is also true for any other CPU related process.
4. Changing number of each threads into 0 will change back multi-thread parallelism settings into default again.