# What is the difference between non blocking and asynchronous calls

Tags: asynchronous, nonblocking

What is the difference when you say the call is non blocking vs when you say the call is asynchronous

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625493/asynchronous-vs-non-blocking

Answer (score 0):

If Asynchronous property for any ajax call is set true then script execution will pause until first request response will not come, That's why it's blocking.