# Asynchronous File I/O via POSIX AIO or Windows Overlapped IO in Java

Tags: java, io, nio, aio, overlapped-io

`System.IO.File` in *.NET* and *.NET Core* has a family of `Read...Async()` methods, all of which return either `Task<byte[]>` or `Task<string>` (`Task<T>` is the *.NET*'s equivalent of *Java's* `Future<T>`).

This looks largely equivalent to `AsynchronousFileChannel` APIs (which either consume a `CompletionHandler` or return a `Future`), with one major difference.

- `AsynchronousFileChannel` uses a managed background thread to perform asynchronous I/O (the thread may be provided either by the default thread pool (`sun.nio.ch.ThreadPool`) or by the `ExecutorService` explicitly specified during channel creation).
- `FileStream` implementation in *.NET*, on the other hand, passes [`FileOptions.Asynchronous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2) flag to the underlying operating system (see also [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/FileIO/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o)), doesn't spawn any managed background threads and uses what is called an [Overlapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O).

#### Questions:

- Is there any (existing or planned) File I/O API in *Java* which would use *Overlapped I/O* on *Windows* and [*POSIX AIO*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html) on Unices? **Update**: *Windows*-specific *Java* runtime features [`sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/ch/WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java) which is exactly an abstraction layer on top of *Overlapped I/O*.
- Are there any plans to provide `java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel` implementations for File I/O? If no, what are the technical limitations?

Answer (score 2):

It is not really possible. The Whole IO API would have to be re-implemented. NIO means non blocking I/O it is not the same as Asynchronous I/O. Non blocking is implemented in JAVA and long story short that means the OS has no ability to notify runtime that operation is completed. Isned java uses `select()` or `poll()` system calls to check if data is available.

I could talk about it but stollen picture is worth 100 words:

[image]

That is why in JAVA the separate thread is required to constantly call check,check,check,check .....

I don't know .NET platform but if what you posted is correct it utilizing asynchronous I/O so the last column. But I don't trust anything that comes from Microsoft.

Hope it answers your question. Also here I a additional reading material:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2625565/8951886

Comment: Okay, but how about `epoll` on Linux, available since 2.6, as well as kernel-accelerated AIO, `O_DIRECT` and friends? How about `kqueue` on Mac OS X and the BSDs? Next, _I/O Completion Ports_ (IOCP) are available not only on Windows, but also on AIX and Solaris 10+ (though the interfaces are of course different). Finally, why not use the POSIX AIO which may be not that advanced as any of the above APIs but much more common?

Comment: @Bass, The interfaces you listed work well with network I/O, for file I/O epoll, for example, always returns that fd is ready, so it's not very efficient.


But, things have changed a bit now that the io_uring interface is available on linux which allows you to implement truly asynchronous file I/O. 

Read more at [io_uring](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf)

File I/O implementation with io_uring - [jasyncfio](https://github.com/ikorennoy/jasyncfio)