Kotlin coroutines: synchronous vs asynchronous, blocking vs non-blocking, concurrent vs parallel
I'm trying to understand the differences and interplay between the terms synchronous and asynchronous, and how blocking and non-blocking fit into this, particularly in the context of Kotlin coroutines. The terms concurrent and parallel also pop up in these settings.
Can anyone please help check and expand on my understanding of these concepts?
Consider a world where we have the following. Task (named Task1) is compromised of four independent operations:
Task1:
* operation 1
* operation 2
* operation 3
* operation 4 

We can think of these operations as method calls. Each operation is independent of one another, meaning that they can be completed in any order, but each are blocking, i.e. only one operation can run at a time on any single thread.
All of these operations must be complete to finish the task
Scenario 1
Consider the thread named Thread1. It needs to perform operation 1 before it can perform operation 2. Hence, this is a blocking scenario, i.e. the thread is blocked at each operation until it's complete.
Thread1 -----operation 1-----operation 2-----> ...

this is also a synchronous scenario by virtue of the fact that there is only one thread available. No other operation (2, 3, or 4) can run while operation 1 is running.
Scenario 2
In a scenario where there are two (or more) threads, we can have blocking operations occurring on either thread.
Thread1 -----operation 1-----operation 2-----> ... 
Thread2 --------operation 3------------operation 4---> ...

In contrast to scenario 1, this is an asynchronous case, where we can have operations running in ?parallel on different threads, even if they block any one of these threads.
Is my understanding correct here?
How do the terms concurrent and parallel fit in here?
In the context of Kotlin and coroutines, how do these concepts fit in?

I recently answered another question where I explained a lot of what you are asking here. Does that help?

There are other really good answers, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625493/asynchronous-and-non-blocking-calls-also-between-blocking-and-synchronous . In the context of Kotlin coroutines only the synchronous/asynchronous term is a little ambiguous. Some people call coroutines synchronous, some say they are asynchronous - depending what they do mean exactly.
