# Python 3: send method of generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I can't understand the `send` method. I understand that it is used to operate the generator. But 
the syntax is here: `generator.send(value)`.

I somehow can't catch why the value should become the result of the current `yield` expression. I prepared an example:

```
def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        X = yield i
        if X == 'stop':
            break
        print("Inside the function " + str(X))

m = gen()
print("1 Outside the function " + str(next(m)) + '\n')
print("2 Outside the function " + str(next(m)) + '\n')
print("3 Outside the function " + str(next(m)) + '\n')
print("4 Outside the function " + str(next(m)) + '\n')
print('\n')
print("Outside the function " + str(m.send(None)) + '\n') # Start generator
print("Outside the function " + str(m.send(77)) + '\n')
print("Outside the function " + str(m.send(88)) + '\n')
#print("Outside the function " + str(m.send('stop')) + '\n')
print("Outside the function " + str(m.send(99)) + '\n')
print("Outside the function " + str(m.send(None)) + '\n')
```

The result is:

```
1 Outside the function 0

Inside the function None
2 Outside the function 1

Inside the function None
3 Outside the function 2

Inside the function None
4 Outside the function 3



Inside the function None
Outside the function 4

Inside the function 77
Outside the function 5

Inside the function 88
Outside the function 6

Inside the function 99
Outside the function 7

Inside the function None
Outside the function 8
```

Well, frankly speaking, it is astonishing me.

1. In the documentation we can read that when a `yield` statement is executed, the state of the generator is frozen and the value of `expression_list` is returned to `next`‘s caller. 
   Well, it doesn't seem to have happened. Why can we execute `if` statement and `print` function inside `gen()`.
2. How can I understand why `X` inside and outside the function differs?
   Ok. Let us assume that `send(77)` transmits 77 into `m`. Well, `yield` expression becomes 77.
   Then what is `X = yield i`? And how 77 inside the function converts into 5 when occurs outside?
3. Why the first result string doesn't reflect anything that is going on inside the generator?

Anyway, could you somehow comment on these `send` and `yield` statements?

Answer (score 74):

When you use `send` and expression `yield` in a generator, you're treating it as a coroutine; a separate thread of execution that can run sequentially interleaved but not in parallel with its caller.

When the caller executes `R = m.send(a)`, it puts the object `a` into the generator's input slot, transfers control to the generator, and waits for a response.  The generator receives object `a` as the result of `X = yield i`, and runs until it hits another `yield` expression e.g. `Y = yield j`.  Then it puts `j` into its output slot, transfers control back to the caller, and waits until it gets resumed again.  The caller receives `j` as the result of `R = m.send(a)`, and runs until it hits another `S = m.send(b)` statement, and so on.

`R = next(m)` is just the same as `R = m.send(None)`; it's putting `None` into the generator's input slot, so if the generator checks the result of `X = yield i` then `X` will be `None`.

As a metaphor, consider a [dumb waiter](http://www.flickr.com/photos/duncan/7458208/):

[image: Dumb waiter]

When the server gets an order from a customer, they put the pad in the dumb waiter, `send` it to the kitchen, and wait by the hatch for the dish:

```
R = kitchen.send("Ham omelette, side salad")
```

The chef (who's been waiting by the hatch) picks up the order, prepares the dish, `yield`s it to the restaurant, and waits for the next order:

```
next_order = yield [HamOmelette(), SideSalad()]
```

The server (who's been waiting by the hatch) takes the dish to the customer and returns with another order, etc.

Because both the server and chef wait by the hatch after `send`ing an order or `yield`ing a dish, there's only one person doing anything at any one time i.e. the process is single threaded.  Both sides can use normal control flow, as the generator machinery (the dumb waiter) takes care of interleaving execution.

Comment: it runs concurrently just not in parallel.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think "concurrently" means in parallel?

Comment: in programming "parallel" implies "concurrent" but the opposite in general is not true. [Difference between concurrent programming and parallel programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1897993/4279)

Comment: This metaphor is awesome. Made my confusions go away. Thanks.

Comment: This one made it click for me.

Comment: but why is it necessary to call next() or send(None) to the chef for the first time?

Comment: @user2297550, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616291/7023590) for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 38):

The most confusing part should be this line `X = yield i`, specially when you call `send()` on the generator. Actually the only thing you need to know is:

in the lexical level:
**`next()` is equal to `send(None)`**

in the interpreter level:
**`X = yield i`** equals to below lines(**ORDER MATTERS**):

```
yield i
# won't continue until next() or send() is called
# and this is also the entry point of next() or send()
X = the_input_of_send
```

and, the 2 lines of comment is the exact reason, why we need to call `send(None)` for the first time, because the generator will return `i` (yield `i`) **before** assign the value to `X`

Comment: Great reply ! Simple and easy explanation. You identified very well the weak point `X = yield i`. 
would upvote 10 times

Comment: "in the lexical level: next() is equal to send(None)". Made my week easier.

Comment: this really helps!

Comment: i don't see why we need to call `send(None)` the first time.  if the first time we `send(7)` then `x` would receive the value `7` so there seems to be no problem?

Comment: Is it correct that the first call to next(m) stops directly after evaluating the right hand side of `yield i`. I.e. it stops before returning any value to `X`? In that case I think I finally understand this. I think this should be the accepted answers. Everywhere else I look I always find convoluted examples that does not help with the understanding.

Comment: @user2297550 As we are able to assign a value to a variable inside a generator only when the generator is executed up to a `yield` statement, we need to call to `g.send(None)` or `next(g)` at first. In practice, sending a value to a generator except for `None` without executing the generator up to a `yield` statement, would result in a `TypeError`.

Comment: @Han thanks for the explanation.  Does it mean that the first `g.send(None`)` will cause the generator to execute up to but not including the `yield` and then I can `g.send(7)` to let `X` get the value `7`?

Comment: @user2297550 No, the first call to `g.send(None)` includes an execution of the first `yield` statement. In other words, it is allowed to send a value to a generator only after the first `yield` statement is executed. I understand that sending a value `g.send(v)` is replacing an yield statement, for example, the rhs `(yield x)` of `y = yield x`. I think the answers to the following question would help you understand. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19892204/5277458

Answer (score 14):

*Note:*
For simplicity, my answer is restricted to the case when the generator has at most 1 `yield` commands in every line.

**TL;DR:**

- The `.send()` method:

  - *sends* a value to the *currently suspended* `yield` command (waking it up), but
  - *receives* a value from the *next, oncoming* `yield` command.
- The recipient of a value sent by `.send()` method is the *yield expression itself.*
  It means that the expression `yield 7`

  - yields value `7`, but
  - its *own value*, i.e. the value of the `(yield 7)`, may be for example  `"hello"`
    (parentheses are generally *mandatory* except the simplest cases) — if this `yield 7` command was woken up by `.send("hello")` method.

---

#### The big picture:

The first `send` (with the `None` parameter) starts the generator instance, so it begins to execute its commands.

[image]

---

#### In detail:

**Preface:**

Let `g = gen()`, i.e. `g` is an instance of a generator iterator `gen()`
(the right-hand side of following pictures).

- The command `next(g)` behaves *exactly as* `g.send(None)`, so you may use whichever you prefer.
- Sending a *not-`None` value* is only allowed if the instance `g` is *suspended at the statement with the `yield` command:*
  [image]

  - *Why?* Because the `.send()` method may send a value only to the *waiting (suspended) `yield` expression* (see the point **4** in the “Step by step” section below).

  So before sending a not-`None` value, we must put the generator instance to such a *suspended state* by sending it the **`None`** value. It may be as simple as `g.send(None)`:

  [image]
- But just before `g` becomes suspended, it yields the value of the `yield` command. This yielded value becomes the return value of the `.send()` method:

  [image]

  We probably want to *use this received value* or save it in a variable for the later use, so instead of the two previous pictures let's start our journey with this:

---

**Step by step:**

1. The first `.send()` starts the instance `g`. Instance `g` begins to execute its commands up to the first `yield` statement, which yields its value:

   [image]

   It means, that in the variable `from_iterator_1` will be the string `"first_from_iterator"`.
2. Now, after yielding its first value, we have `g` in the suspended state

   [image]

   which allows us sending to `g` something **useful**, other than `None` — e.g. the number `1`.
3. So let's send the number `1` to `g`:
   [image]
4. As `g` was suspended at the *expression* `yield "first_from_iterator"`,
   the value of *this expression (itself)*  will become `1`.

   (Yes, the `yield "first_from_iterator"` **is** an expression, likewise `a + b` is.)

   Recall that at this moment the value `"first_from_iterator"` is long time ago already yielded.
5. The instance `g` then wakes up, and — in turn — the `g.send()` now waits for a returned value.
   [image]
6. The previously suspended, now woken statement will be executed.
   (Before the suspension, *it was not executed, it only yielded a value.*)
   [image]
   In our simple case (the woken statement is `yield "first_from_iterator"`) there remains nothing to be performed, but what about

   - saving the received value (`1`) to a variable for the later use instead?

     ```
     received_1 = yield "first_from_iterator"
     ```
   - or performing a more complicated computation with it instead?

     ```
     result = 3 * (yield "first_from_iterator") + 2           # result: 5
     ```
7. All consequent statements in `g` will be performed, but only up to the next  statement with the `yield` command in it.

   [image]
8. That next statement (with the `yield` command in it) *yields a value*

   [image]

   which suspends `g` again, and wakes up the waiting `.send()` method (by providing it the awaited — yielded — return value).
9. It allows performing next commands after it:

   [image]
10. Now we are **in the same situation as in the point 2.** — just before performing the (next) `.send()` method — so the **story will be repeated**.

    *Note:*
    It will be repeated *with the same issue* as in the last point of the “Preface” section above — we probably don't want to throw out the yielded value, so instead of the commands

    ```
    g.send(1)                          # Not very appropriate
    ```

    is better to use something as

    ```
    from_iterator_2 = g.send(1)        # Saving the 2nd yielded value
    ```

    (and similarly for the next `g.send(2)` command).

Answer (score 7):

```
def gen():
    i = 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        x = yield i
        print(x)

m = gen()
next(m)
next(m)
m.send(4)
```

result

```
None
4
```

look at more simplified codes above.
I think the thing leaded to your confusion is 'x = yield i' statment, 
this statment is not saying value accepted from send() method assgined to i then i assgined to x.
Instead, value i is returned by yield statment to generator, x is assgined by send() method.One statement does two thing at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked even for comments, consider the following case:

```
def lambda_maker():
    def generator():
        value = None
        while 1:
            value = yield value
            value= value[0][1]
    f = generator()
    next(f)  # skip the first None
    return f.send  # a handy lambda value: value[0][1]
```

Now the following two lines are equivalent:

```
a_list.sort(key=lambda a: a[0][1])
a_list.sort(key=lambda_maker())
```

(Incidentally, in the current (2018-05-26, day 1 post-GDPR ☺) CPython2 and CPython3 implementations, the second line runs **faster** than the first, but that's a detail related to frame object initialization overhead on every function call.)

What happens here? `lambda_maker` calls `f=generator()` and gets a generator; calling the initial `next(f)` starts running the generator and consumes the initial `None` value, and pauses at the `yield` line. Then it returns the bound method `f.send` to its caller. From this point on, every time this bound method is called, the `generator.value` local receives the argument of the bound method, recalculates `value` and then loops back `yield`ing the current value of `value` and waits for the next `.send` to get another value.

The generator object stays in-memory and all it does in the loop is:

- **yield** the current result (initially None)
- **receive** another value (whatever someone used as argument to `.send`)
- re-calculate current result based on received value
- loop back

Comment: Having an explicit `a_list` would help to understand the example...