# How does "line = (yield)" work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

I was reading a Python textbook when I saw this piece of code:

```
def print_matches(matchtext):
    print "Searching for", matchtext
    while True:
        line = (yield) 
    if matchtext in line:
        print line

matcher = print_matches("python")
matcher.next()
matcher.send("Hello World")
matcher.send("python is cool") # prints "python is cool"
matcher.send("yow!")
matcher.close()
```

I always considered it a kind of `return`-sibling, so now I am really interested how `(yield)` works. Some people referred me to [the Python 2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) and [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).

But as I am not a native speaker it's really hard for me to understand anything written in there. Could anyone please tell me in as simple language as possible how `(yield)` works?

I understand the syntax when you use "yield" to return object on demand. But I don't understand the implementation of "line = (yield)". Why "yield" is a value of a variable?

Comment: What do you mean *"how does it work"*? You mean how is it implemented? Or just how does one use it (in which case, there are plenty of examples out there already, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/3001761)

Comment: I'd recommend these presentations on [generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/finalgenerator/) and [coroutines](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand the syntax when you use "yield" to "return" object on demand. But I don't understand the implementation of "line = (yield)". Why "yield" is a value of a variable?

Comment: So it's the assignment and `.send` you're unclear on? What is puzzling you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe only the assignment. I've never seen such use of this statement before.

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19302530/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that cleared it a lot!

Comment: @Ben Thanks for those links a lot!

Comment: You should change the title of your question to `How does "line = yield" work?`

Comment: The answer to your question is `line = yield` _and_ `matcher.send('string')` together let you implement a _coroutine_, that is a generator with a twist, you can modify its status using its `.send()` method.  For further details you have already the links in the excellent comments from Ben and johnrsharpe.

Comment: @gboffi Thak you for your advise and clear explanation!

Comment: I know this is old, but this may help someone. This presentation by D. Beasley is the best explanation http://dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf. . .The 1st part explains what `line = yield` does & how it does it.