# Python generator coroutine

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Trying to understand a bit more of the generator/send function in python.  I read some in the link: [generator send function purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) which helped a lot.

But I am trying to understand the code below.  Why is the `next(checker)` necessary?  Doesnt the send function automatically ask for the next item in the generator?  I tried just having the `next(checker)` before the for loop but that doesnt function the same way.  I thought the send function sends 'attempt' as x and yields whether `x == password`.  I just dont understand why its necessary to have the next(checker) in the loop.

```
def checkPassword(attempts, password):
    def check():
        while True:
            x = yield
            yield x == password

    checker = check()
    for i, attempt in enumerate(attempts):
        next(checker)
        if checker.send(attempt):
            return i + 1

    return -1
```

The function above is base on the problem:

"In order to validate your function, you want to test it locally. Given a list of attempts and the correct password, return the 1-based index of the first correct attempt, or -1 if there were none.

Example

For `attempts = ["hello", "world", "I", "like", "coding"]` and
`password = "like"`, the output should be
checkPassword(attempts, password) = 4."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Doesnt the send function automatically ask for the next item in the generator?

Yeah, but the way this generator is written, half the values come from this `yield`:

```
x = yield
```

which just yields `None`. The calls to `next` consume the `None`.

---

The generator could have been written differently, to eliminate most of the `next` calls:

```
def checkPassword(attempts, password):
    def check():
        x = yield
        while True:
            x = yield x == password

    checker = check()
    next(checker)
    for i, attempt in enumerate(attempts):
        if checker.send(attempt):
            return i + 1

    return -1
```

However, the `yield`/`send` communication between a generator and its user cannot start with a `send`, since a fresh generator is stopped at the beginning of the function body instead of at a `yield` that could receive a value. Thus, there always has to be a `next` (or equivalently a `send(None)`) before you can start `send`ing values the generator will use.

Comment: I still dont understand fully. x = yield just yields None? I thought x = yield is executed when the send function is called, passing attempt to x, then yield true or false back?

Comment: @user1179317: The `x =` part is executed when you call `send`. When you call `next`, the generator advances to the `yield`, yields `None`, and pauses. When you call `send`, the object you sent becomes the value of the `yield` expression and is assigned to `x`, and the return value of `send` comes from the next `yield`.

Comment: Okay, i think i got it. Thanks

Comment: @user1179317 hope this link works but here is a [visual](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/fluent-python/9781491946237/images/flup_1601.png.jpg) from [fluent python](https://www.amazon.com/Fluent-Python-Concise-Effective-Programming/dp/1491946008/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491511629&sr=8-1&keywords=fluent+python)