# Using defer module in python to execute a bunch of tasks async

Tags: python, asynchronous, deferred, gil

I saw this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) suggesting the usage of defer module to execute a series of tasks asynchronously.

I want to use it for my Project:

1. Calculate the median of each list of numbers I have (Got a list, containing lists of numbers)
2. Get the minimum and maximum medians, of all medians.

But for the matter of fact, I did not quite understand how to use it.

I would love some explanation about defer in python, and whether you think it is the appropriate way achieving my goal (considering the Global Interpreter Lock).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer talks about Twisted there; you want to watch  my colleague [Łukasz Langa explain asynchronous programming at Pycon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4Nn-y9ktd4) and use Python 3.5 or newer to get the benefit of using the more readable `async`/`await` syntax to achieve the same.

Comment: That said, using coroutines gives you better latency control in I/O heavy applications. CPU-heavy applications (like calculating stats on numbers), will **not** benefit. Use multiprocessing instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using asynchronous programming (*cooperative routines*, aka coroutines), will not help your use case. Async is great for *I/O intensive workloads*, or anything else that has to wait for slower, external events to fire.

Coroutines work because they give up control (*yield*) to other coroutines whenever they have to wait for something (usually for some I/O to take place). If they do this frequently, the event loop can alternate between *loads* of coroutines, often far more than what threading could achieve, with a simpler programming model (no need to lock data structures all the time).

Your use-case is not waiting for I/O however; you have a *computationally heavy workload*. Such workloads do not have obvious places to yield, and because they don't need wait for external events, there is no reason to do so anyway. For such a workload, use a [multiprocessing model](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to do work in parallel on different CPU cores.

Asynchronous programming does not defeat the GIL either, but does give the event loop the opportunity to move the *waiting for I/O* parts to C code that can unlock the GIL and handle all that I/O processing in parallel while other Python code (in a different coroutine) can execute.

See [this talk by my colleague Łukasz Langa at PyCON 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4Nn-y9ktd4) for a good introduction to async programming.