# What is the python syntax when a variable is after 'yield'?

Tags: python, generator, yield, yield-keyword

```
def minimize():
    current = yield
    while True:
        value = yield current # what is this????
        current = min(value, current)
```

I got this piece of code from [here](https://effectivepython.com/2015/03/10/consider-coroutines-to-run-many-functions-concurrently/). 
Here is the quote:

" The generator function receives the value passed to the send function as the result of the corresponding **yield expression.**"

note: it says yeild expression, which mean the whole "yield current" thing. Is my understanding correct? If so, why not just use "yield", removing "current" from the expression??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python generator "send" function purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302530/2988730)