# Why does the yield expression collapse?

Tags: python, yield

I was messing around and noticed that the following code yields the value once, while I was expecting it to return a generator object.

```
def f():
    yield (yield 1) 
f().next() # returns 1

def g():
    yield (yield (yield 1) 
g().next() # returns 1
```

My question is what is the `value` of the `yield` expression and also why are we allowed to nest yield expression if the yield expression  collapses?

Comment: Related/Dup: [yield(x) vs. (yield(x)): parentheses around yield in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/37845338)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The value of the [`yield` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) after resuming depends on the method which resumed the execution. If `__next__()` is used (typically via either a `for` or the `next()` builtin) then the result is `None`. Otherwise, if `send()` is used, then the result will be the value passed in to that method.

So this:

```
def f():
    yield (yield 1)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
def f():
    x = yield 1
    yield x
```

Which in this case (since you're not using `generator.send()`) is equivalent to this:

```
def f():
    yield 1
    yield None
```

---

Your code is only looking at the first item yielded by the generator. If you instead call `list()` to consume the whole sequence, you'll see what I describe:

```
def f():
    yield (yield 1)

def g():
    yield (yield (yield 1)) 


print(list(f()))
print(list(g()))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 yield.py 
[1, None]
[1, None, None]
```

---

If we iterate the generator manually (as you have), but `.send()` it values, then you can see that `yield` "returns" this value:

```
gen = f()
print(next(gen))
print(gen.send(42))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 yield_manual.py 
1
42
```

Comment: It's not really true that `yield` returns `None`. Rather, it returns the value that you [`send`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) to the generator. (And simply iterating over a generator is like calling `send(None)`.)

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey, I've been trying to find the relevant part of the documentation to elaborate on that.