# Python generator that produces and receives values

Tags: python

Can someone explain how yield is working in the code below?

```
def countdown(n):
    print("Counting down from", n)
    while n >= 0:
        newvalue = (yield n)

        if newvalue is not None:
            n = newvalue
        else:
            n -= 1

c = countdown(5)
for n in c:
    print n
    if n == 4:
        c.send(2)
```

output

```
('Counting down from', 5)
5
4
1
0
```

I expected it to be

```
('Counting down from', 5)
5
4
2
1
0
```

Where is "2" getting lost?

Tracing these two events (receive and produce) simultaneously is getting a bit trickier. This is not a duplicate of [python generator "send" function purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) because that question is mostly focused on understanding the need for coroutines and how they defer from generators. My question is very specific to a problem with using coroutines and generators together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python generator "send" function purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose)

Comment: @muru actually it is not a duplicate. I have updated the question please check it again.

Comment: The examples in the duplicate makes this clear.

Comment: I would recommend you to check out the [`A Curious Course on
Coroutines and Concurrency`](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf) presentation by David Beazley.

Answer (score 1):

[The duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose) has the relevant documentation:

> The send() method returns **the next value yielded by the generator**[.]

[And this answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302700/2072269) illustrating how control moves back and forth with `send()` is useful here. First, add additional `print`s to illustrate what's happening:

```
def countdown(n):
    print("Counting down from", n)
    while n >= 0:
        newvalue = (yield n)
        print (newvalue, n) # added output

        if newvalue is not None:
            n = newvalue
        else:
            n -= 1

c = countdown(5)
for n in c:
    print n
    if n == 4:
        print(c.send(2))   # added output.
```

You'll see:

```
('Counting down from', 5)
5
(None, 5)
4
(2, 4)
2
(None, 2)
1
(None, 1)
0
(None, 0)
```

With the `send(2)`, control passed to the function, `newvalue = (yield n)` is continued, and the loop goes once around to the next yield, stopping again, but the value yielded this time is returned by `send(2)`, *not* by the next iteration of the for loop. There's your `2`.