# How to make sense of the use of `yield` in PyMC models?

Tags: python, generator, yield, pymc

I am not a user of PyMC myself, but recently I stumbled upon [this article](https://eigenfoo.xyz/manipulating-python-asts/#the-problem) that showed a snippet of some PyMC model:

```py
def linear_regression(x):
    scale = yield tfd.HalfCauchy(0, 1)
    coefs = yield tfd.Normal(tf.zeros(x.shape[1]), 1, )
    predictions = yield tfd.Normal(tf.linalg.matvec(x, coefs), scale)
    return predictions
```

The author suggested that users

> would be uncomfortable with `bar = yield foo`

Uncomfortable indeed I am. I tried to make sense of this generator, but couldn't see how it can be used.

This is my thought process. If I do `foo = linear_regression(bar)` and execute `foo` (e.g. `next(foo)`), it will return the value of `scale` to me. However, this will also turn the local variable `scale` to `None`. Similarly, if `foo` is executed again, I can get the value of `coefs`, but the local `coefs` would become `None`. With both local `scale` and `coefs` being `None`, how can `predictions` be evaluated?

Or is there a way to evaluate `foo` without triggering the `yield` on `scale` and `coefs`, and directly yield on `predictions`?

What is the black magic here? Help needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclosure: I'm the author of the [original linked article](https://eigenfoo.xyz/manipulating-python-asts/).

I think your main misunderstanding is this: Python generators can not only yield values to you, but you can also *send back* values to generators using `generator.send()`. Thus, `bar = yield foo` would yield `foo` to you; the generator will wait until you send it another value (which can be `None`, which is what happens if you just call `next(generator)`!), assign that value to `bar`, and then continue running the generator.

Here's a simple example:

```py
>>> def add_one_generator():
...     x = 0
...     while True:
...         x = yield x + 1
...
>>> gen = add_one_generator()
>>> y = gen.send(None)  # First sent value must be None, to start the generator
>>> print(y)
1
>>> z = gen.send(2)
>>> print(z)
3
```

Notice that when I `send(2)`, the generator assigns the sent value to `x`, and then resumes execution. In this case, that just means `yield x + 1` again, which is why the yielded `z` is `3`.

For more info on this pattern and why it might be useful, take a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302694/13372802).

Here's some pseudocode that brings us closer to how things will (probably) work in PyMC4:

```py
>>> def linear_regression(x):
...     scale = yield tfd.HalfCauchy(0, 1)
...     coefs = yield tfd.Normal(tf.zeros(x.shape[1]), 1, )
...     predictions = yield tfd.Normal(tf.linalg.matvec(x, coefs), scale)
...     return predictions
>>> model = linear_regression(data)
>>> next_distribution = model.send(None)
>>> scale = pymc_do_things(next_distribution)
>>> coefs = pymc_do_things(model.send(scale))
>>> predictions = pymc_do_things(model.send(coefs))
```

Comment: Very surprised to have the author of the article answer my question. Thanks for the explanation. I suppose the reason PyMC4 constructs API this way is that user can inject `scale` and `coefs` as they wish, right?

Comment: Almost: it allows the _PyMC4 inference engine_ to inject `scale` and `coefs` as it wishes. The user-specified model generator yields the distributions to PyMC4, and PyMC4 will interact with these distributions and re-inject the distribution into the model generator.

Comment: over a year later, this is such a wholesome conversation, and I love it! Yay, stackoverflow!