# Python's SendType and ReturnType in Generators

Tags: python-3.x, generator

So I was tinkering with generators, and i found out that generators have a `typing` object (i.e. generators have an alias)
I then stumbled upon documentation for the `typing.Generator` object on https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator and this is what the docs have to say:

> *A generator can be annotated by the generic type `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]`.*

Which got me wondering on how to modify the `SendType` and `ReturnType` thingys
The docs suggested this as an example:

```py
def echo_round() -> Generator[int, float, str]:
    sent = yield 0
    while sent >= 0:
        sent = yield round(sent)
    return 'Done'
```

I assume that the second `sent` declaration is what defines the `SendType`, but `yield 0` returns `None` (or doesnt return anything in the first place), and therefore raises `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

How does `SendType` work, how do I modify it, and what are cases in which `SendType` and `ReturnType` are useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generators have a [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) method:

> #### `generator.send(value)`
>
> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function. The value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression. The `send()` method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or raises `StopIteration` if the generator exits without yielding another value. When `send()` is called to start the generator, it must be called with `None` as the argument, because there is no yield expression that could receive the value.

See also [What's the purpose of "send" function on Python generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/whats-the-purpose-of-send-function-on-python-generators)

So with your generator you can do this:

```
it = echo_round()
print(next(it))      # 0 -- we could also have printed: it.send(None) 
print(it.send(1.1))  # 1
print(it.send(2.5))  # 2
print(it.send(-1.8)) # StopIteration: Done
```

> ...but yield 0 returns None

...unless we call `send` after the first yield has been made, like in the above script. Here `yield 0` will return 1.1

We see all three types at play here:

`it.send(1.1)` takes a value of the *SendType* (`float` in this case), and returns a value of the *YieldType* (`int` in this case), or raises a `StopIteration` error with a value of the *ReturnType* (`str` in this case).

Comment: Thank you! I learned more about generators in python