# Missing print task when generator is invoked

Tags: generator, python-3.6, pascals-triangle

I have written the following code to produce pascal-triangle like pattern for three different heights. Each time, a different character is used to get the pattern. I am able to get the ones with '*' and '&', but the second call for printing with '=' never gets invoked. So, the corresponding pattern is missing on the screen. Tried to debug by interleaving input() statement between the three calls, but of no avail. Please help.

```
def draw_triangle(pattern_values):

    def draw(ht, ch):
        for i in range(1, ht+1):
            print('{txt:^{wid}}'.format(txt=i*(ch+' '),wid=2*ht))

    draw(pattern_values[0], pattern_values[1])
    yield pattern_values

    while True:
        pattern_values = yield pattern_values
        draw(pattern_values[0], pattern_values[1])

pattern_series = draw_triangle([10, '*'])
next(pattern_series)
pattern_series.send([12, '=']) # This does not produce any output
pattern_series.send([14, '&'])
```

Comment: You should know that **yield** working similar as **return**. Except one thing: it returns generator instead of result. So *code after your first yield will never be run*.

Comment: No. Then, I should not have got a triangle printed with '&'. But, I do get this besides the starting one with '*'. To generate a series of odd numbers ad infinitum, you can use a next statement followed by send. The generator will have a simple yield followed by one inside an infinite loop (while True) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just use this fuction as generator without initial values.

```
def draw_triangle(pattern_values=""):

    def draw(ht, ch):
        for i in range(1, ht+1):
            print('{txt:^{wid}}'.format(txt=i*(ch+' '),wid=2*ht))

    while True:
        pattern_values = yield pattern_values
        draw(pattern_values[0], pattern_values[1])

pattern_series = draw_triangle()
next(pattern_series)
pattern_series.send([10, '*'])
pattern_series.send([12, '=']) # This does not produce any output
pattern_series.send([14, '&'])
```

Comment: Yes, it produces the desired output. But, may I know what happens to next(pattern_series) and the corresponding yield statement? Why don't I get the print() statement's output corresponding to this?

Comment: @SeshadriR, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892204/send-method-using-generator-still-trying-to-understand-the-send-method-and-quir) is good explanation of this behavior.