# TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add the on_member_join() methods, so that I can be notified using my own custom messages when someone joins.

So I have a channel called main-channel on my server, which is where I want those welcome messages to be printed by the bot. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing that.
This is currently my setup, but it doesn't work.

The error I get is:

> Ignoring exception in on_member_join
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\frenc\PycharmProjects\Discord\discord\client.py", line 255, in _run_event
>       await coro(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:/Users/frenc/PycharmProjects/Discord/prova.py", line 18, in on_member_join
>       await channel.send("Benvenuto nel Server!")
>   TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
>   C:\Users\frenc\PycharmProjects\Discord\discord\client.py:262: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Member._get_channel' was never awaited
>     pass

I don't really have any idea on how to make my bot print these messages to that specific channel on my server.

I use the latest version of discord and Python 3.6.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('-----')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    channel = member._get_channel()
    await channel.send("Welcome to the server!")
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="@everyone")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
    print("Added role '" + role.name + "' to " + member.name)

client.run(myToken)
```

Comment: Can you post the full type error, specifically need to know which line is causing the error. This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892204/send-method-using-generator-still-trying-to-understand-the-send-method-and-quir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this error because you did not await `_get_channel`.  Coroutines/generators have a `send` method that has nothing to do with the `send` method of [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) objects.

You shouldn't be using that coroutine anyway, as `Member` objects are themselves messageable:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
    await member.send("Welcome to the server!")
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)

    # Probably unnecessary
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="@everyone")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
    print("Added role '" + role.name + "' to " + member.name)
```

If `@everyone` is supposed to be the default role, you don't need to add it to members, they will get it automatically (the point being that everyone has the `everyone` role at all times).