# What is the behavior of `.close()` on a generator that has just started?

Tags: python, generator

What is the behavior of `.close()` on a generator that has just started?

```py
def gen():
  while True:
    yield 1

g = gen()
g.send(1)
```

throws `TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator`

```py
def gen():
    while True:
        try:
            yield 1
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("exit")
            raise

g = gen()
next(g)
g.close()
```

prints `exit`

But what is the behavior of:

```py
def gen():
    while True:
        try:
            yield 1
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("exit")
            raise

g = gen()
g.close()
```

and how can I check it?

EDIT:

When I try it, nothing happens, but subsequent calls to `next(g)` raise `StopIteration`.

My question is actually: what happens in terms of memory, but I guess most is freed.

Comment: Did you try it? ("Try it" isn't a fully reliable way to know what something does, since you don't know if it'll *always* do the same thing, but... you tried the first two code blocks. Why not the last one?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send method using generator. still trying to understand the send method and quirky behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892204/send-method-using-generator-still-trying-to-understand-the-send-method-and-quir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the docs (shortened):

> Raises a GeneratorExit at the point where the generator function was
> paused.

> close() does nothing if the generator has already exited

When it was not started, it couldn't be paused or exited. The case it was not started (with an initial `next` or `send`) is not mentioned.

But we could easily check that not a single statemenet from the generator function was executed before `.close()` and no statement could be executed after the `.close()`.

That is the only logical behaviour, IMO. There is nothing to be cleaned up in the generator function, because it did not get a chance to run.