# Iteration in python taking acount the previous output values

Tags: loops, iteration, repeat

I am new in Python and I would like to ask this question:

I want to write a code, which repeats itself *taking into account the previous values*.

For example let us we want firsly to have as output the difference between 100 (:= an initial value, which we need to define in inside the loop) and our input number x. Thus, if the first time we give the value 5 for x, then the first output is 95. We want the second to be *95 minus *the new* given x*, so, if the second x is 3, our second difference will be 95-3= 92 and so on til e.g. the difference will be 0.

If this example helps, I would be glad for some help to understand the general method.

I would like to understand a loop in python with these specific characteristics. I f this simple example helps, I would be happy to get understanding through that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this idea quite interesting, I came up with the following example:

```
import itertools

def sub_to_zero(val):
    while val > 0:
        sub = (yield val)
        if sub is not None:
            val -= sub
    yield None

subs = itertools.cycle([5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4])
nums = sub_to_zero(100)

nums.send(None)
while True:
    x = nums.send(next(subs))
    if x is None:
        break
    print(x)
```

The key idea is to use a generator with an initial value, and then make use of the `.send()` method to decrement that value each time we want to access the next item.

For general info on generators and using send: https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/#how-to-use-send

For info on the quirky initial `send(None)` that is needed: [Send method using generator. still trying to understand the send method and quirky behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892204/send-method-using-generator-still-trying-to-understand-the-send-method-and-quir)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems interesting and I will study it but I think I cannot understand it immediately. I waas thinking something more simple such 'for' command and an iterative code with i =1,2,3, etc. Is it something like that possible?

Comment: I would be happy to help simplify it.  Is the generator (sub_to_zero) confusing or the surrounding code, or all of it?  If you could update your question with a template of what you have so far, that would also be helpful.