# Python Coroutines that receive and emits return values

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming

I am reading Python Essential Reference and I am unable to understand coroutine which receive and emits return values.

Here is what the author says -
"A coroutine may simultaneously receive and emit return values using yield if values are supplied in the yield expression."

Here is an example that illustrates this:

```
def line_splitter(delimiter=None):
    print("Ready to split")
    result = None
    while True:
        line = (yield result)
        result = line.split(delimiter)
```

Further the author adds,
In this case, we use the coroutine in the same way as before. However, now calls to
send() also produce a result. For example:

```
>>> s = line_splitter(",")
>>> s.next()
Ready to split
>>> s.send("A,B,C")
['A', 'B', 'C' ]
>>> s.send("100,200,300")
['100', '200', '300']
```

I want to know how the above code works.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/471899

Comment: Hard to answer unless you can tell us which part you don't understand. Do you have a good understanding of the generator aspect?

Comment: What I know about generators is that it uses yield keyword and produces a sequence of values used for iteration.
I am not able to understand the working of above mentioned code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what the calling code does, line by line:

- `s = line_splitter(",")` This line just initializes the generator, *without* executing any of the code within it.
- `s.next()` This executes the code up to and including the next `yield` statement, printing the line and yielding `None`. The assignment `result = ...`, however, is *not* executed yet.
- `s.send("A,B,C")` This sets the "value" of `yield` *within* the generator to `"A,B,C"` and executes the code up to and including the next `yield`, thus assigning it to `result`.

In a sense, the `yield` keyword can be used for both, getting values *out* of the generator (using `next`) and at the same time injecting values *into* the generator (using `send`).

For a more in-depth explanation, you might also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638313/1639625).