# What happens when you invoke a function that contains yield?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, abstract-syntax-tree, yield

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302530/python-generator-send-function-purpose/60042174?noredirect=1#comment109042384_60042174) the following example:

```
>>> def double_inputs():
...     while True:      # Line 1
...         x = yield    # Line 2
...         yield x * 2  # Line 3
...
>>> gen = double_inputs()
>>> next(gen)       # Run up to the first yield
>>> gen.send(10)    # goes into 'x' variable
```

If I understand the above correctly, it seems to imply that Python actually waits until `next(gen)` to "run up to" to `Line 2` in the body of the function. Put another way, the interpreter would **not** start executing the body of the function until we call `next`.

1. Is that actually correct?
2. To my knowledge, Python does not do AOT compilation, and it doesn't  "look ahead" much except for parsing the code and making sure it's valid Python. Is this correct?
3. If the above are true, how would Python know when I invoke `double_inputs()` that it needs to wait until I call `next(gen)` before it even enters the loop `while True`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Calling `double_inputs` never executes any of the code; it simply returns a `generator` object.  The presence of the `yield` expression in the body, discovered when the `def` statement is *parsed*, changes the semantics of the `def` statement to create a `generator` object rather than a `function` object.

Answer (score 2):

The function contains `yield` is a generator.

When you call `gen = double_inputs()`, you get a generator instance as the result. You need to consume this generator by calling `next`.

So for your first question, it is true. It runs lines 1, 2, 3 when you first call `next`.

For your second question, I don't exactly get your point. When you define the function, Python knows what you are defining, it doesn't need to look ahead when running it.

For your third question, the key is `yield` key word.

Answer (score 0):

Generator-function is **de iure** a function, but **de facto** it is an iterator, i.e. a **class** (with implemented `__next__()`, `__iter()__`, and some other methods.)

#### In other words, it is a class *disguised as a function.*

It means, that “calling” this function is in reality *making an instance of this class*, and explains, why the “called function” does initially *nothing*. This is the answer to your 3<sup>rd</sup> question.

---

The answer to your 1<sup>st</sup> question is surprisingly **no**.

Instances always wait for calling its methods, and the `__next__()` method (indirectly launched by calling the `next()` build-in function) is not the only method of generators. Other method is the `.send()`, and you may use `gen.send(None)` instead of your `next(gen)`.

---

The answer to your 2<sup>nd</sup> question is **no**. Python interpreter by no mean "look ahead" and there are *no exceptions*, including your

> ... except for parsing the code and making sure it's valid Python.

Or the answer to this question is **yes**, if you mean “parsing *only* up to the next command”. ;-)

Comment: You may see a more complex picture in my other [illustrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616291/7023590).