# What do the different (HotSpot) JVM thread types do?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I see there are six thread types implemented into the HotSpot JVM: VMThread, CGCThread, PGCThread, JavaThread, CompilerThread and WatcherThread. However I don't know which thread type is doing what exactly. Here is what I understood so far:

- VMThread: run VM tasks like the garbage collector.
- CGCThread: Concurrent garbage collector.
- PGCThread: Parallel garbage collector (differences with CGC?).
- JavaThread: Program's threads, I guess.
- CompilerThread: A thread for the compiler?
- WatcherThread: ?

Additional question: what about other JVMs?

Comment: Parallel vs concurrent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897993/difference-between-concurrent-programming-and-parallel-programming

Comment: PCG vs CGC in Hotspot: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors

Comment: The CompilerThread is for the JIT compiler.

Comment: Some info about the WatcherThread here: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksrini/entry/we_take_java_performance_very

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a brief explanation on the [OpenJDK website](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html#Thread%20Management%7Coutline):

> The main kinds of VM threads are as follows:
>
> - VM thread: This singleton instance of VMThread is responsible for    executing VM operations, which are discussed below
> - Periodic task    thread: This singleton instance of WatcherThread simulates timer    interrupts for executing periodic operations within
>     the VM
> - GC threads: These threads, of different types, support parallel and    concurrent garbage collection
> - Compiler threads: These threads perform runtime compilation of bytecode to native code
> - Signal dispatcher thread: This thread waits for process directed signals and dispatches    them to a Java level signal handling method

You might want to read the whole Thread Management paragraph since it continues further explanations, e.g. what the VM thread is responsible for.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to comments, we have the beginning of an answer:

1) Since the garbage collector has a stop-the-world mecanism, there exist besides tunings two ways to reduce these pauses:

- With parallel GCs running via PGCThreads such that, if n cores are available, then n threads can be run during pauses to shorten them.
- With a concurrent GC, running via a CGCThread and finishing the job of the regular GC off pauses, concurrently with the main program thread.

2) The CompilerThread runs the Just-In-Time compiler.

3) The WatcherThread simulates timer interrupts every 50ms to run periodic operations in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

And I would add that there are **7** threads type in [JVM](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/hotspot/file/d3cc20285653/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp#l446)!  Don't miss `os_thread`

path: Defined in: `/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp`

```
  enum ThreadType {
    vm_thread,
    cgc_thread,        // Concurrent GC thread
    pgc_thread,        // Parallel GC thread
    java_thread,       // Java, CodeCacheSweeper, JVMTIAgent and Service threads.
    compiler_thread,
    watcher_thread,
    os_thread
  };
```