# Does JVM contain all threads/process that a java program runs?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

If I run a java program, does JVM contain it as a child process/thread?

To be specific, when JVM runs, I know that it has many different type of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46916213/7748163). But I am confused, is java/mutator process/thread encapsulated inside JVM? Does JVM spawn java/mutator process/thread?

I use `pstree -p {java_pid_from_top}` to get the following graph. If so, one of children may be java/mutator process/thread?

[image]

[image] from [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/java-virtual-machine-work-makeuseof-explains/)

Comment: The JVM is a process. Each Java program runs in its own process. But each process has several threads.

Comment: Yes, some of these threads are JVM threads, others are application threads. They all have the same owner (parent) process.

Comment: Hard to answer, as it is entirely unclear what “java/mutator process/thread” is supposed to mean.