# In a multi-core processor, how can I find the simulation time of the slowest core?

Tags: performance, parallella

(Sorry if I phrased the question incorrectly)

I am running some applications on a 16-core Parallella board and I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the amount of time taken by the slowest core?

I think that if I add the **`user`** + **`sys`** times, I will get the sum of the execution times for all the cores, correct?

These are some of the results:

```
real        0m1.927s
user        0m3.190s
sys         0m0.080s
```

Answer (score 1):

### Disambiguation

There is a strong difference between a **multi-core** based mode of operations, arranged in a "concurrent" manner and a **parallel** mode processing.

On Parallella board, if speaking about `Zynq` -- a dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 CPU / Xilinx 7-series on chip FPGA -- for that you can get **`user`** + **`sys`** values from on-board linux. Not the same for the **`Epiphany MPPA`** ( Massive Parallel Processor Array ) hardware device or additional parallelisable **`FPGA`**-hardware loadable soft-CPU-cores.

Also note, that on a truly parallel system, the word "slower" or "slowest" core, loses its meaning as all processors start and finish in a parallel manner, for details kindly see the **`PAR`** syntax constructor in **`occam-pi`**  ( even at a cost of waiting for a divergent alternative path of processing, so as they all finish in parallel ).

### How to?

One may include some signalling data to store during MPPA code-execution a clock counter value / later retrieved from Linux/ARM-side and use these telemetry-records data to evaluate ex-post the code-execution timing pre-recorded "inside-MPPA".

Doing the same in-real-time might be possible for in-vivo Tracing / State-Diagnostics / Inspect-Analyse-Tool but would require a lot of system specific engineering efforts for such a Real-Time-SysMONITOR.

However this is doable. Similar approach was used for visual inspection of state-transitions in FSA-design / validation.

[A good explanation of conceptual and performance difference between a **`PARALLEL`**, **`SERIAL`** and **`CONCURRENT`** mode of code-execution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347539/3666197)