# Python zeromq pipeline pattern

Tags: python, zeromq

I am trying to implement a pipelining pattern with Python and ZeroMQ therefore I created the three components: `producer`, `consumer` and `merger`

So, I am able to send my tasks, consume (calculate square of a number), and then get my results.

**My question is**, if I have a list of tasks I plan to submit as a batch and I want them to be completed in a distributed pool of resources and merge the results, similar to multiprocessing apply/apply_async.

In native python, I typically use

```
    ...

    def f(n):
      return n*n

    ...
    _r=[]
    for i in xrange(1000): 
      _r.append(pool.apply_async(f,(i,)))
    ...
    #get results
    results = [ r.get() for r in _r ]
```

I am trying to emulate this into zeromq pattern

I am basing my **`producer`**, **`consumer`**, **`results`** with this [example](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html). I also plan to have several servers as consumers since its a long running task therefore I have looked at the load-balancing pattern and the daunting [cluster pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Architecture-of-a-Single-Cluster). Is this necessary for zero mq?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>... original post has changed both the wording of the question ( excluding inital request for a `PARALLEL` processing ) and has shifted the target.

This answer started **before** these updates
when
the O/P contained
 a question

. . . how do I know my first **batch results are ready?**</sup>

### How do I know my first ... is the easier part:

The **`result_collector`** end of the processing pipeline can either **`.poll()`** it's **`PULL`** receiver associated with a **`zmq.Poller`** instance, so as to test for a presence of a first appearance of **`zmq.POLLIN`** event.

Or, may get hands a bit dirty and handle the same `PULL`-engine "sniffing" by a construct alike
 **`try: .recv( ..., zmq.NOBLOCK ) except ZMQError: #noMsgYetHandler`**

---

### Parallel? In case you require indeed a PARALLEL ... it is VERY HARD

In recent decade, many texts use a word parallel. Still, there is a very limited number of cases, where a true **<kbd>PARALLEL</kbd>** code execution is possible.

[This post may help for a **fast disambiguation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639672/3666197) and another link there will help strictly separate a case, [**on what conditions** a **true <kbd>PARALLEL</kbd>** software system design has to be implemented.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347539/3666197)

In case your Project fits into **`[ 1.Definition ]`** of a **true <kbd>PARALLEL</kbd>** system, your ZeroMQ efforts will also have to provide a robust, minimum latency signalling and ultra-low latency control-plane facilities for tru-parallel-system execution ( which **is out-of-question doable**, however your Project's man*days consumption & know-how + QM/QA requirements have exploded into several orders of magnitude larger investment / V@R scale )

---

### CONCURRENT solution fits just-right?

If **<kbd>CONCURRENT</kbd>** system operations design is enough ( be it a blocking-permitted or a high-level top-down non-blocking system architecture design ), you will have many direct ZeroMQ tools for designing smart services, round-robin or priority-queue-flagged ( so thus btw inherently non-parallel, just concurrent ) load-balancers and many handy ready-to-use features under this ***"relaxed"*** system design paradigm.