# Akka Future - Parallel versus Concurrent?

Tags: scala, akka, future

From the well-written [Akka Concurrency](http://www.artima.com/shop/akka_concurrency):

[image]

As *I understand*, the diagram points out, both `numSummer` and `charConcat` will run on the same thread.

Is it possible to run each `Future` in parallel, i.e. on separate threads?

Comment: Arguably, the figure should be called "Flatmapping concurrently versus sequentially", given that the left one is the concurrent one....

Comment: But `concurrent` implies re-using the same thread, no?

Comment: Not necessarily, as far as I understand it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897993/difference-between-concurrent-programming-and-parallel-programming or https://blogs.oracle.com/yuanlin/entry/concurrency_vs_parallelism_concurrent_programming; sequential would be when there is no overlap between executions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The picture on the left *is* them running in parallel.

The point of the illustration is that the `Future.apply` method is what kicks off the execution, so if it doesn't happen until the first future's result is `flatMap`ed (as in the picture on the right), then you don't get the parallel execution.

(Note that by "kicked off", i mean the relevant `ExecutionContext` is told about the job. How *it* parallelizes is a different question and may depend on things like the size of its thread pool.)

Equivalent code for the left:

```
val numSummer = Future { ... }  // execution kicked off
val charConcat = Future { ... }  // execution kicked off
numSummer.flatMap { numsum =>
  charConcat.map { string =>
    (numsum, string)
  }
}
```

and for the right:

```
Future { ... }  // execution kicked off
  .flatMap { numsum =>
    Future { ... }  // execution kicked off (Note that this does not happen until
                    // the first future's result (`numsum`) is available.)
      .map { string =>
        (numsum, string)
      }
  }
```