# Asynchronous Javascript: Run two functions at the same time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to improve my understanding of asynchronous JavaScript. To do this I have made a function that can take a long time to complete, which would completely block any other code from executing.

To test this, the function counts up. the first call counts from 1 to 10000000. The second call counts from 10 to 100.

**CODE**

```js
async function LongTask(from, to) {
    //Count up
    let myNum = from
    console.log(`counting from ${myNum} to ${to}`)
    let start = new Date();

    while (myNum != to) {
        //console.log(`myNum: ${myNum}`);
        await myNum++;

    }
    let end = new Date();
    console.log(`counting from ${from} to ${to} done in ${end - start}ms!`);
}

//2 functions that take some time to finish
LongTask(1, 10000000);
LongTask(10, 100);

//Do unrelated stuff
console.log("Hello World!");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
counting from 1 to 10000000
counting from 10 to 100
Hello World!
counting from 10 to 100 done in 2ms!
counting from 1 to 10000000 done in 40389ms!
```

I managed to get it so that 10 to 100 will finish first due to it being faster. However, I get a warning on line 10 `await myNum++;` saying **'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.** Removing the `await` keyword results in code blocking making it so that the 10 to 100 call of the function will have to wait for the much longer, unrelated 1 to 10000000 call to finish before being called.

Am I misunderstanding how asynchronous JavaScript works and is there a better way to ensure the 10 to 100 call finishes first?

Comment: `await` only makes sense when used with Promises. You can't really await anything else, it'll just yield the value and continue.

Comment: Think you can do multiple async await using Promise.all with async await, try it

Comment: counting isn't very good for this type of illustration because they are both basically instantaneous. Use a [sleep function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) to ensure that one takes longer than the other. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc7nsu2k/)

Answer (score 0):

You can only await a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise?retiredLocale=de) which your function (and every `async` function) returns. You'll have to `await` both promises at some point in order to make sure the program does not exit before the promises resolve.

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await multiple promises. I altered your example to await a predefined time span to illustrate how this works, as I then exactly know when I expect a function to finish.

```js
(async() => {
  async function LongTask(ms) {
    console.log(`starting task that will take ${ms} milliseconds`)
    await waitFor(ms);
    console.log(`ended task that took ${ms} milliseconds`);
  }

  async function waitFor(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
  };

  //2 functions that take some time to finish
  const start = new Date();
  console.log(`Calling both functions at ${start}`)
  const countToSmallNumberPromise = LongTask(4000);
  const countToLargeNumberPromise = LongTask(1000);

  //Do unrelated stuff
  console.log("Hello World!");
  // await both promises to make sure they finish before the program finishes
  await Promise.all([countToLargeNumberPromise, countToSmallNumberPromise])
  const end = new Date();
  // program will end after approx. 4 seconds (at least 4 seconds), so both functions actually run in parallel 
  // (that's actually not correct, there is no real parallelism here, as Node or your browser are single-threaded)
  // To be correct: they run concurrently, not in parallel.
  console.log(`Ending program at ${end}. Program ran for ${end - start} milliseconds`);
})();
```

> FYI: [Difference between **concurrent** and **in parallel**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897993/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrent-programming-and-parallel-programming)

Comment: Your `Promise.all` isn't doing anything here since you aren't capturing the return of it and the `log` calls are included in the `LongTask`. (remove it and the output will be the same)

Comment: Yes you're right, noticed it right away :D I've corrected the program