# Difference between a "coroutine" and a "thread"?

Tags: architecture, multithreading, system, coroutine

What are the differences between a "coroutine" and a "thread"?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Coroutines are a form of sequential processing: only one is executing at any given time (just like subroutines AKA procedures AKA functions -- they just pass the baton among each other more fluidly).

Threads are (at least conceptually) a form of concurrent processing: multiple threads may be executing at any given time.  (Traditionally, on single-CPU, single-core machines, that concurrency was simulated with some help from the OS -- nowadays, since so many machines are multi-CPU and/or multi-core, threads will *de facto* be executing simultaneously, not just "conceptually").

Comment: I think this answer's terminology is confusing and maybe wrong. Today, coroutine implementations like [Python's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) are said to be concurrent. The coroutines still work exactly as you've described—they "pass the baton among each other"—it's just that we count that as a form of concurrent processing.

Comment: So coroutines utilize Threads under the hood, and Threads can use multiple cores if available. So In theory 2 coroutines using different threads can run in parallel.

Answer (score 349):

**First read:** [Concurrency vs Parallelism - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050222/concurrency-vs-parallelism-what-is-the-difference)

> Concurrency is the separation of tasks to provide interleaved
>   execution. Parallelism is the simultaneous execution of multiple
>   pieces of work in order to increase speed. —https://github.com/servo/servo/wiki/Design

**Short answer:** With threads, the operating system switches running threads preemptively according to its scheduler, which is an algorithm in the operating system kernel. With coroutines, the programmer and programming language determine when to switch coroutines; in other words, tasks are cooperatively multitasked by pausing and resuming functions at set points, typically (but not necessarily) within a single thread.

**Long answer:** In contrast to threads, which are pre-emptively scheduled by the operating system, coroutine switches are cooperative, meaning the programmer (and possibly the programming language and its runtime) controls when a switch will happen.

> In contrast to threads, which are pre-emptive, coroutine switches are
>   cooperative (programmer controls when a switch will happen). The
>   kernel is not involved in the coroutine switches.
>   —http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/overview.html

A language that supports **native threads** can execute its threads (user threads) onto the operating system's threads (**kernel threads**). Every process has at least one kernel thread. Kernel threads are like processes, except that they share memory space in their owning process with all other threads in that process. A process "owns" all its assigned resources, like memory, file handles, sockets, device handles, etc., and these resources are all shared among its kernel threads.

The operating system scheduler is part of the kernel that runs each thread for a certain amount time (on a single processor machine). The scheduler allocates time (timeslicing) to each thread, and if the thread isn't finished within that time, the scheduler pre-empts it (interrupts it and switches to another thread).  Multiple threads can run in parallel on a multi-processor machine, as each thread can be (but doesn't necessarily have to be) scheduled onto a separate processor.

On a single processor machine, threads are timesliced and preempted (switched between) quickly (on Linux the default timeslice is 100ms) which makes them concurrent. However, they can't be run in parallel (simultaneously), since a single-core processor can only run one thing at a time.

**Coroutines** and/or **generators** can be used to implement cooperative functions. Instead of being run on kernel threads and scheduled by the operating system, they run in a single thread until they yield or finish, yielding to other functions as determined by the programmer. Languages with **generators**, such as Python and ECMAScript 6, can be used to build coroutines. Async/await (seen in C#, Python, ECMAscript 7, Rust) is an abstraction built on top of generator functions that yield futures/promises.

In some contexts, **coroutines** may refer to stackful functions while **generators** may refer to stackless functions.

**Fibers**, **lightweight threads**, and **green threads** are other names for coroutines or coroutine-like things. They may sometimes look (typically on purpose) more like operating system threads in the programming language, but they do not run in parallel like real threads and work instead like coroutines. (There may be more specific technical particularities or differences among these concepts depending on the language or implementation.)

For example, Java had "**green threads**"; these were threads that were scheduled by the Java virtual machine (JVM) instead of natively on the underlying operating system's kernel threads. These did not run in parallel or take advantage of multiple processors/cores--since that would require a native thread! Since they were not scheduled by the OS, they were more like coroutines than kernel threads. Green threads are what Java used until native threads were introduced into Java 1.2.

Threads consume resources. In the JVM, each thread has its own stack, typically 1MB in size. 64k is the least amount of stack space allowed per thread in the JVM. The thread stack size can be configured on the command line for the JVM. Despite the name, threads are not free, due to their use resources like each thread needing its own stack, thread-local storage (if any), and the cost of thread scheduling/context-switching/CPU cache invalidation. This is part of the reason why coroutines have become popular for performance critical, highly-concurrent applications.

Mac OS will only allow a process to allocate about 2000 threads, and Linux allocates 8MB stack per thread and will only allow as many threads that will fit in physical RAM.

Hence, threads are the heaviest weight (in terms of memory usage and context-switching time), then coroutines, and finally generators are the lightest weight.

Comment: +1, but this answer could benefit from some references.

Comment: Green threads are some thing different than coroutines. are they not ? Even fibers have some differences. see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254140/is-there-a-difference-between-fibers-coroutines-and-green-threads-and-if-that-i

Comment: Agreed, Threads are not light weight. That wrong term has its impact. As far as context switching is concerned, it has a cost equal to a process. If we create thousands of threads, it is as heavy as equal number of processes (w.r.t context switches). At that time, co-routines are serious alternatives to think.

Answer (score 206):

About 7 years late, but the answers here are missing some context on co-routines vs threads. Why are **coroutines** receiving so much attention lately, and when would I use them compared to **threads**?

First of all if coroutines run **concurrently** (never in **parallel**), why would anyone prefer them over threads?

The answer is that coroutines can provide a *very high level of concurrency* with *very little overhead*. Generally in a threaded environment you have at most 30-50 threads before the amount of overhead wasted actually scheduling these threads (by the system scheduler) *significantly* cuts into  the amount of time the threads actually do useful work.

Ok so with threads you can have parallelism, but not too much parallelism, isn't that still better than a co-routine running in a single thread? Well not necessarily. Remember a co-routine can still do concurrency without scheduler overhead - it simply manages the context-switching itself.

For example if you have a routine doing some work and it performs an operation you know will block for some time (i.e. a network request), with a co-routine you can immediately switch to another routine without the overhead of including the system scheduler in this decision - yes you the programmer **must** specify when co-routines can switch.

With a lot of routines doing very small bits of work and voluntarily switching between each other, you've reached a level of efficiency no scheduler could ever hope to achieve. You can now have thousands of coroutines working together as opposed to tens of threads.

Because your routines now switch between each other a pre-determined points you can now also **avoid locking** on shared data structures (because you would never tell your code to switch to another coroutine in the middle of a critical section)

Another benefit is the much lower memory usage. With the threaded-model, each thread needs to allocate its own stack, and so your memory usage grows linearly with the number of threads you have. With co-routines, the number of routines you have doesn't have a direct relationship with your memory usage.

And finally, co-routines are receiving a lot of attention because in some programming languages (such as Python) your *threads cannot run in parallel anyway* - they run concurrently just like coroutines, but without the low memory and free scheduling overhead.

Comment: How to do a switching to another task in coroutines when we encounter a blocking operation?

Comment: The way you switch to another task is to have any blocking operation actually done async. This means you have to avoid using any operation which would actually block, and only use operations that support not blocking when used in your coroutine system. The only way around this is to have coroutines supported by the kernel, such as UMS on Windows for example, where it jumps into your scheduler whenever your UMS "thread" blocks on a syscall.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Is the recent C++ Threads TS adhering to the approach you mentioned?

Comment: So eventually a modern programming language would need both Coroutines/Fibers to efficiently utilize a single CPU core for e.g non-computation-heavy operations like IO and Threads to parallelize CPU intensive operations on many cores to gain speed, right?

Comment: @MartinKonecny *thousands of coroutines vs tens of threads*!!!. can you add some reference to it?

Answer (score 26):

12 Years late to the discussion but a coroutine has the explaination in the name. Coroutine can be decomposed into Co and Routine.

A routine in this context is just a sequence of operations/actions and by executing / processing a routine the sequence of operations gets executed one by one in the exact same order as specified.

Co stands for cooperation. A co routine is asked to (or better expected to) willingly suspend its execution to give other co-routines a chance to execute too. So a co-routine is about sharing CPU resources (willingly) so others can use the same resource as oneself is using.

A thread on the other hand does not need to suspend its execution. Being suspended is completely transparent to the thread and the thread is forced by underlying hardware to suspend itself. It is also done in a way so that it is mostly transparent to the thread as it does not get notified and it's state is not altered but saved and later restored when the thread is allowed to continue.

One thing that is not true, that co-routines can not be concurrently executed and race conditions can not occur. It depends on the system that the co-routines are running on and it is easy possible to imaging co-routines .

It does not matter how the co-routines suspend themselves. Back in Windows 3.1 int 03 was woven into any programs (or had to be placed in there) and in C# we add yield.

Answer (score 23):

In a word: preemption. Coroutines act like jugglers that keep handing off to each other a well-rehearsed points. Threads (true threads) can be interrupted at almost any point and then resumed later. Of course, this brings with it all sorts of resource conflict issues, hence Python's infamous GIL - Global Interpreter Lock.

Many thread implementations are actually more like coroutines.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the language you're using. For example in Lua [they are the same thing](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html) (the variable type of a coroutine is called `thread`).

Usually though coroutines implement voluntary yielding where (you) the programmer decide where to `yield`, ie, give control to another routine.

Threads instead are automatically managed (stopped and started) by the OS, and they can even run at the same time on multicore CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

coroutine means it is a cooperative function that runs asynchronously in the system
while thread is also a light-weight process, that run parallel on the system .
Thread can share the memory and resources of the parent process.
In the operating system , thread have a limited amount of memory while co-routine doesn't need any memory because co-routine execute on the thread. co-routine are more use as compared to thread.