# What is the difference between Coroutine, Coroutine2 and Fiber?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-asio

There are 3 thin threads with manual low-latency context switching in the Boost:

- Boost.Coroutine: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html
- Boost.Coroutine2: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/index.html
- Boost.Fiber: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html

What is the difference between Coroutine1, Coroutine2 and Fiber in Boost?

Comment: Coroutine is deprecated in favor of Coroutine2. Other than that, it's essentially the difference between [threads and coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934715/difference-between-a-coroutine-and-a-thread)

Comment: @CoryKramer Fibers aren't threads. So yeah, it's on that spectrum, but more faceted.

Comment: as a side note, for my taste the `co_await` TS is really simpler and more elegant than all of the above.

Comment: @david I thought the proposal was for stackless coroutines, but boost had stackful?

Comment: @DavidHaim as a side note to your side note, I'm really sad they went with the co_ prefix.

Comment: @Yakk they are different, Gor's proposal is about stackless coroutines, while boost provides stackfull coroutines. considering the latter actually requires you to write so much code **and** it uses much more memory, I simply don't see why using these in the first place

Comment: @Borgleader I agree. but prefix or not, this feature rocks!

Comment: @DavidHaim Stackless solve a certain subset of problems but do it more efficiently.  Stackfull lets you do more insane things; I spent a semester messing around with stackful back in university, and it does have lots of power.  Might not be worth the cost, and I didn't try to reimplement what I did using stackless.  But my point is they are very different beasts with the same name.

Comment: @David Haim, if you want yield from a deep call stack using resumable functions, **all** functions in the call stack must be resumabel functions too (what if you call thrid party, library functions in the call stack). Note that each resumable function needs memory to store local vars, registers, function state - the memory is allocated dynammically (performance?). Additionally - resumable functions benefit from compiler support, the boost implementation is library only. I haven't seen equivalent libraries using resumable functions that provide an API like boost.coroutine2 or boost.fiber.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**boost.coroutine** is non-C++11 and therefore requires to use a private API from boost.context (reason because it is deprecated).

**boost.coroutine2** and **boost.fiber** require C++11 and use **callcc()/continuation** (implements context switch, call-with-current-continuation) from boost.context.

**boost.coroutine** and **boost.coroutine2** implement coroutines, while **boost.fiber** provides fibers (== lightweigt, coroperative userland-threads, green-threads, ...) with an API similar to std::thread.

The difference between coroutines and fibers is described in [N4024: Distinguishing coroutines and fibers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4024.pdf) - in short: fibers are switched by an **internal scheduler** while coroutines use **no internal scheduler**.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the linked N4024!
Sidenote: AFAIK python's asyncio does essentially that: I uses python generators (coroutines) to provide a scheduler and some fibers for asnychronous io :)