# Rxjava with kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I am in need that i need to start the coroutines from rxkotlin chain, But am i not sure whether this is right or wrong, to start a coroutines from the rx chain i use `runblocking` to start the suspend methods
**Example**

```
Single.just(someOperation())
   .map{
     someMethod(it)
   }
  .flatMap{
    startCoroutines(suspend { someOpeartions() } ) // i will be starting the coroutines here
  }
```

**Coroutines**

```
fun startCoroutines(suspendingObj : suspend () -> Any){
  runBlocking(newFixedThreadPoolContext(1,"Thread")){
       suspendingObj.invoke()
  }
}
```

Is this above code is correct way of doing it or is there is any other way to achieve this ?
Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: Why do you need coroutines if it's already inside the chain? I guess it should either rx or coroutines.

Comment: @TentenPonce is this wrong way of doing if so why ?

Comment: rx is already asynchronous, why do you want to use coroutines inside it? if your goal is to change thread, it is already supported on rx `.observeOn()`. You can just instead of suspend, just make it rx and add it on your current chain.

Comment: Blocking is almost never a good choice, Rx or no Rx. [There exist](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2) converters and builders that can bridge the two approaches. For example [rxSingle](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.-coroutine-scope/rx-single.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code chunk is fundamentally wrong.

1. In your case it is really not necessary to use Coroutines, because you can easily change Rx thread before `flatMap` with `observeOn` and pass any `Scheduler` you want (like IO).
2. Kotlin Coroutines were designed to avoid `Threads`, because creating `Threads` is a very expensive operation. And your function `startCoroutines` creates a new thread for every operation which makes no sense and potentially will cause `overflow`. You can read more about it here: [Difference between a "coroutine" and a "thread"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934715/difference-between-a-coroutine-and-a-thread)
3. You should always try to find a better system design before deciding using `runBlocking`. Blocking threads is never a good idea.