# Tornado difference between run in executor and defining async methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado, scheduledexecutorservice

I am pretty new to Tornado. I can't understand the difference between using `run_on_executor` and defining an `async` method. Is it the same? Is the one multithreaded and the other not?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`run_on_executor` is for interfacing with blocking non-async code.

You are correct that async code is only executed in a single thread.
Maybe an example would illustrate the point.

Let's say your Tornado web service interfaces with a library that makes use of `requests` to fetch country info for a given IP address. Since `requests` is a non-async library, calling this function would block the Tornado event loop.

So, you have two options: try to find the replacement for the library that is async-compatible OR run the blocking code in a different thread/process and have your event loop `await` its result like for normal async code without blocking the event loop. The latter option is `run_on_executor` which allows you to run the task in different thread or process, and asyncio would "await" its completion.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs

> Utilities for working with Future objects.
>
> Tornado previously provided its own Future class, but now uses
> asyncio.Future. This module contains utility functions for working
> with **asyncio**.Future in a way that is backwards-compatible with
> Tornado’s old Future implementation.
>
> While this module is an important part of Tornado’s internal
> implementation, applications rarely need to interact with it directly.

As I understand `run_on_executor` from `tornado.concurrent` is a way of interacting with `asyncio.Future` with backwards compatibility to old Tornado's `Future`

In any case, any code based in `asyncio` is not using multithreading, it's using **coroutines**

This medium post may help you understand the differences between `asyncio` and `threads`: [here](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-sync-async-concurrency-and-parallelism-166686008fa4)

Comment: In any case, any code based in asyncio is not using multithreading, it's using coroutines

Are coroutines and multithreading essentially the same thing?

Comment: The docs explain it better than I ever will, for clarification on coroutines (they are a little bit difficult to grasp due to the name) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934715/difference-between-a-coroutine-and-a-thread

A coroutine is basically an event loop running on a single thread (look at Concurrency and Multithreading). -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html

Comment: the main difference between threads and coroutines is how they are scheduled. threads are pre-emptive This means that threads do not need to explictly yield control to their scheduler, the scheduler will preempt threads itself. Where as in case coroutines each coroutine is resposinble for yielding their control,  Otherwise they will block all of the other coroutines.