# Relationshipt between async/await, generators and coroutines

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, coroutine

In JavaScript we always had promises. Then async/await came into the language, which I thought was a wrapper around promises. Then generators came into the language with `yield` keyword, which started to look very much like coroutines.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436125/2545680) states that:

> Coroutines and/or generators can be used to implement cooperative functions. Instead of being run on kernel threads and scheduled by the operating system, they run in a single thread until they yield or finish, yielding to other functions as determined by the programmer. Languages with generators, such as Python and ECMAScript 6, can be used to build coroutines. **Async/await** (seen in C#, Python, **ECMAscript 7**, Rust) **is an abstraction built on top of generator functions that yield futures/promises.**

It talks about both async/await and generators as a wrapper for coroutines implementation. This seems to be the case in Python, but is it so now in JavaScript as well?

Comment: since JS as a language doesn't link `async/await` with generators I guess there's no reason for the implementers to mandatory use generators for implementing `async/await`. so my guess no ECMAScript7 mentions that either.

Comment: Ecmascript doesn't have "coroutines" in the specification that I am aware of. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "*In JavaScript we always had promises. Then async/await came into the language. Then generators came into the language*" - you've got your history confused. The first (popular) promise libraries came around 2010, and they were just libraries not part of the language. With ES6 (2015), both promises and generator functions became standardised, and were implemented natively. Then async/await came with ES8 (2017).

Comment: Recall generators are based on iterators, which are expected to produce a value from a series; coroutines (as in cooperative multitasking) need not return any value from their logic as the context of their scope is more involved in arbitrarily control flow rather than of a particular series. Check out [Promises](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_promises.html), [Generators as Coroutines](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#sec_generators-as-coroutines) and/or [AsyncAwait](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_async-functions.html) from the books by  A. Rauschmayer for more.

Comment: [A General Theory of Reactivity](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor) might also be helpful to read.

Comment: @AshtonEngberg, awesome, thank you very much for the recommendation!

Comment: No problem, when I first started down this rabbit hole, one of the first articles I came across was [Notes on structured concurrency...](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/) which is conceptually general enough it sets up the stage for understanding the underlying theme shared by all languages on this topic.

Comment: lots of interesting stuff! :D

Comment: There's a lot more too! Take care to note the date of your source material, as lot has changed (~standardized) since 10 years ago; A Raushmayer's are up to date but you might also check out [YouDontKnowJS 1stEdition](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md) and [Javascript Allongé 6th Edition](https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read#interactive-generators). These last two are very useful if you weren't programming over that period of time, you get 1st person POV of JS's evolution as a language.

Comment: [Node.js control flow-an overview](https://www.capitalone.com/tech/software-engineering/overview-of-nodejs-asynchronous-flow-control/) by Noah Mandelbaum probably comes close to answering your question. Also: 1) `async`/`await` act to wrap and unwrap asynchronous operation as a promise. 2) These two emerged out of the need to fix the callback hell nested promises's IoC introduced. 3) They share that they pause and resume execution with how generators `yield`; with the point being to be capable of writing async code that looks (and be reasoned about as if) it's synchronous.

Comment: @AshtonEngberg thanks, could you publish your comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: This weekend I will have some free time (I think) to do so... just in the last three days came across half a dozen more links [increasingly](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async) [relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRbqLGj_6mI)! Anyways my answer would be more of a follow up / extended notes-background; I think Daniel Hakobyan's concise answer could qualify as acceptable if the connection to Javascript were made more explicit (eg, incrementally comparative even if trivial examples of actual code; hypothetically for instance, a "new" Javascripter might not even know what goto refers too!).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, JavaScript async/await is still a wrapper around promises. They may be implemented now with generators but they still work like promises.

If you don’t await a JavaScript async function, it still runs.

```js
async function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}
foo(); // logs "foo" as expected
```

But because of the way Python coroutines are implemented they have to be awaited using asyncio or from another async function.

```py
async def foo():
    print("foo")

foo()
# you get:
#
# Warning (from warnings module):
#   File "test.py", line 4
#     foo()
# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
#
# and no "foo" prints out
```

Comment: thanks! doesn't answer my question, but the warning from the python gives me an insight into Python's implementation

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines are a control flow mechanism. You can reimplement coroutines by using goto and mutating an address both sides have access to. As such a coroutine is to goto, what for loops are to while loops. A form of sugar.

Async/await requires arbitrary suspension and resumption of functions so builds off of coroutines. As goto would be horrible to work with. However the async/await pattern specializes coroutines with a scheduler to manage the coroutines.

You can build your own async/await scheduler in any language which supports coroutines (not generators, which only support unidirectional communication). Which is how Python had support for the async/await pattern way before async and await were added to the language.

> in some languages, that distinction is a bit blurry.

If the only coroutines the language supports are async/await ones then users likely can conflate the two concepts.

> coroutines are not necessarily asynchronous

Coroutines have nothing to do with asynchronous. Asynchronous (async/await) requires* coroutines to work.

*: T&C apply

> if the consensus is that they are just synonyms, then perhaps one
> should be made a synonym of the other (or just removed)?

The two terms are not synonymous. As such the coroutine tag shouldn't be removed because of such a train of thought.

Comment: [Also you can read this](https://medium.com/@adambene/async-await-vs-coroutines-vs-promises-eaedee4e0829)