# Read Locks and Write Locks

Tags: database, multithreading, concurrency, transactions, locking

I am a little unsure about read and write locks and just need someone to check if these facts about read/write locks are correct.

This is in reference to databases in general.

Read Locks:

1. Multiple read locks can be acquired by multiple threads at the same time.
2. When a thread has a read lock on a row/table, no thread can update/insert/delete data from that table. (Even if the thread trying to write data doesn't require a write lock.)
3. A row/table cannot have a read and a write lock at the same time.

Write Locks:

1. When a row/table has a write lock, it cannot be read by another thread if they have a read lock implemented in them but can be read by other threads if no read lock is implemented (i.e simple Select query)

Thanks for the clarification. I cant find direct assertions to these statements on the internets.

Answer (score 27):

In **database management** theory, locking is used to implement [isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) among multiple database users txn. This is the "I" in the acronym [ACID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69526030/1697099) (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability). Locks are applied by a TX (transaction) to data, which may block other TXs from accessing the same data during the TX's life.

**Simple Locking:** Two main types of locks can be requested:

- *Shared lock:* Read lock i.e. Any other TX(or multiple TXs) can read but not write (lock shares with multiple txs i.e. Shared lock)
- *Exclusive lock:* Write lock i.e. No other TX can read or write (lock not shares with any other txs i.e. exclusive lock)

**Multiple Locking:** *Two Phase Locking (2PL)* is a concurrency control method that guarantees serializability.

- A *Growing/Expanding/First Phase*: locks are acquired and no locks are released.
- A *Shrinking/Contracting/Second  Phase*: locks are released and no locks are acquired.

Answer (score 22):

Read Locks:

1. Multiple read locks can be acquired by multiple threads at the same time.

   **True. Multiple read locks can exist at the same time. (Read lock has another name: Shared lock)**
2. When a thread has a read lock on a row/table, no thread can update/insert/delete data from that table. (Even if the thread trying to write data doesn't require a write lock.)

   **True. The write transaction should wait for read locks to finish reading.**
3. A row/table cannot have a read and a write lock at the same time.

   **True. If you have the write lock before the read lock, the write lock will block other transactions to read or write the same table. If you have the read lock before the write lock, the read lock will block the write transactions until the reading transaction finishes.**

Write Locks:

1. When a row/table has a write lock, it cannot be read by another thread if they have a read lock implemented in them but can be read by other threads if no read lock is implemented (i.e simple Select query)

   **Sorry, I don't understand this statement.**
   **But when a table has a write lock (Exclusive Lock), it can not be read or written by another transaction.**

Comment: I think for the last statement, what @nknj means is that if the other transaction has a transaction isolation level set as READ_UNCOMMITED - in which case it need not take a shared lock and is allowed to read the row which is not yet committed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) level used.

Comment: Does it mean that there in no specific meaning of locks, it's an abstraction in isolation levels?

Comment: No, locks have a very specific meaning. Isolation is about the way locks are used.

Comment: Can you please share some link, or maybe article name about locks. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, though have intermediate knowledge. But here is something about locks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science) and about transaction processing in databases where isolation is needed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing

Comment: Down voting since the answer could've been a lot more elaborate.