# How to make queries atomic in PostgreSQL stored procedures?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, atomic, plpgsql

I think the balance will be updated incorrectly if one process select the balance from a unique userid and attempts to do the insert, but another process reads the balance before that happens. How do I fix this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION incBalance(INTEGER, BIGINT) RETURNS void AS $$   
DECLARE   
    balanceRecord record;
    newBalance bigint;  
BEGIN   
    FOR balanceRecord IN    
        SELECT balance FROM users WHERE userid = $1
    LOOP
        newBalance := balanceRecord.balance + $2;
        UPDATE users SET balance = newBalance WHERE userid = $1;   

    END LOOP; 
    RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this particular query, you could rewrite it as a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE users SET balance = balance + $2 WHERE userid = $1;
```

More generally, you want to let the transaction system handle atomicity and data consistency.  In Postgres, stored procedures are always executed inside a transaction context - if you aren't calling it from an explicit transaction block, it will create one for you.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/static/sql-set-transaction.html discusses how to set the isolation level if the default isn't stringent enough.

You will want to read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/static/mvcc.html to help decide which level is appropriate for a particular stored procedure.  Note sections 13.2.2 and 13.2.3 which warn that higher isolation levels are subject to serialization exceptions that should be caught and the transaction retried as a mechanism for ensuring consistency.

If I have such a procedure, I add a statement at the beginning of the procedure's first BEGIN block to ensure the transaction is running at a sufficient isolation level.  If **no** work has been done in the transaction yet, it will raise it if necessary.  If the calling context was a transaction that **has** done work, it will cause an error if the enclosing transaction block had not already raised the isolation level sufficiently.  It will **not** lower the isolation level if it was already higher than what you specify here.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Comment: What happens if we, say, execute simultaneously thousands of queries, each of which makes `balance = balance + $2` for that specific user? Wouldn't it be that at some point `balance` would be taken from older time, increased/decreased by $2, loosing some intermediate additions/decreases? And why?

Comment: @PF4Public The whole point of using an [ACID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740280/acid-and-database-transactions) compliant database is so you can avoid such problems.  ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED is sufficient for the single UPDATE statement shown.  More complex transactions may warrant a higher level as is discussed in the documentation links provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifications