# Linked server was unable to begin a distributed transaction when query is inside a TransactionScope

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a query that involves a Linked server. The query runs fine in SSMS and when wrapped around in C# using Dapper

```
 var conn = GetOpenConnection(connInitializer);
 return query(conn);
```

produces expected result. However, when I put the code inside a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx),

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
     var conn = GetOpenConnection(connInitializer);
     var returnValue = query(conn);
     trans.Complete();
     return returnValue;
}
```

I got an Error:

"The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server xxx  was unable to begin a distributed transaction."

Should I modify some SQL Sever configuration to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're executing the query inside an explicit transaction, you are requiring that the query follows [these ACID properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740280/acid-and-database-transactions). You'll need to [configure Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2027550) to manage the transaction across data sources.

Since query worked originally outside the scope of a transaction, I'm guessing it's a simple select. If that's the case, you may want to consider opening separate connections for each data source, loading the **required** data in application objects, and merging from there to produce results.

Otherwise, be prepared to troubleshoot MSDTC connectivity issues and to monitor the transaction queue for orphaned transactions.