# what is difference between atomicity and isolation in ACID properties?

Tags: database

the difference between atomicity and isolation of DBMS is somewhat vague so i am asking for a clear difference between the two ?

Atomicity and isolation, are ensured in classical database transactions by using a commit protocol. This protocol is used to turn temporary storage into permanent storage - that is, the updates to the transaction's data are not visible until the commit protocol validates the stored data. Note that it is the presence of a commit record in the database log which effectively validates the transaction's data.

Comment: some tutorial shows the above definition but i'm not cleared with that can any help me

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740307/3869557

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACID and database transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740280/acid-and-database-transactions)

Comment: Seems like Isolation is a necessary consequence of Atomicity. Feels kind of redundant.

Answer (score 9):

Atomicity describes the behavior within an individual transaction, and Isolation describes the behavior among one or more transactions.

**Atomicity**: Either all of the database operations in a transaction are executed or none are.

**Isolation**: Each transaction appears to execute in isolation from other transactions.

Comment: Amazing answer!!

Answer (score 2):

**Atomicity**: all operations in a transaction are executed as a single unit.

**Isolation**: transactions don't see intermediate changes of other transactions.

According to these definitions, **Isolation is just a part of Atomicity**. Because when other transactions can see intermediate impact of our transaction, operations of our transaction cannot be considered as a single atomic unit.

Answer (score 1):

Atomicity means if **ONE** transaction contains multiple operations, either **ALL** of them or **NONE** are performed.

The counterintuitive point is, this definition still allows for interleaving the operations with other transactions. As a result, atomicity itself does not guarantee isolation.

Example: Transaction A and B both contain two operations:

```
Transaction A:
A1: Read Alice's account balance
A2: Add 100 and write it back to Alice's balance

Transaction B:
B1: Read Alice's account balance
B2: Add 50 and write it back to Alice's balance
```

Suppose now Alice's balance is 0, and transactions A and B happen concurrently in the order of A1-B1-B2-A2, what is the final balance? It's 100.

Both A and B are atomically committed, in the sense that all their operations occurred. But without proper isolation, the result is probably not what you want.

Comment: Why does atomicity mean isolation when talking about atomic operations at the operation level (linearisation of the operations) , but apparently doesn't mean isolation (serialisation of the transactions) when talking at the transaction level?