# Oracle update same column in several tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column, `person_id`, in several tables in my database.  I'm getting rid of duplicates in my `individuals table` and need to update the `person_id` in the rest of the tables.

My schema is `clud` and my tables are:

```
address
cases
child_cases
matter_person
phone
individuals
```

How can I update all the tables at once instead of doing them individually?

*Individuals table*

```
person_id | first_name | last_name
----------------------------------
100        John         Doe
101        John         Doe  (duplicate value)
```

I want to delete the record where person_id is 101 and I need to change the person_id in all other tables to 100 where the person_id is 101.

*Cases Table*

```
person_id | case_number
-----------------------
100        12345
101        6789
```

Result

```
person_id | case_number
-----------------------
100        12345
100        6789
```

*matter_person Table*

```
person_id | matter_number
-------------------------
100         123abc
101         456def
```

Result

```
person_id | matter_number
-------------------------
100        123abc
100        456def
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: In SQL's set-based paradigm and RDBMS' transaction-based [ACID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740280/how-do-acid-and-database-transactions-work) framework, you would not be able to *update all the tables at once*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sample data is above

Comment: You would need a SQL transaction to update `person_id` in all the tables that reference the Individuals table, then delete the duplicate person records, and finally commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic SQL such as

```
DECLARE
  v_pid_new individuals.person_id%type := 100;
  v_pid_old individuals.person_id%type := 101;  
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE column_name = 'PERSON_ID' )
  LOOP
   IF c.table_name = 'INDIVIDUALS' THEN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE '||c.table_name||' WHERE person_id=:pido' USING v_pid_old;     
   ELSE
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||c.table_name||' SET person_id=:pidn WHERE person_id=:pido' USING v_pid_new,v_pid_old;  
   END IF;  
     COMMIT;
  END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29e7b52cf60054d4720a4f77537099d5)</kbd>

Comment: If the person_id is used in foreign key constraints it may be necessary to order the statements to update child tables before parent tables. There may be other challenges (eg a person can only have one current/primary address)

Comment: well, thanks @GaryMyers , that might also be considered.