# Writing multithreaded methods using async/await in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a small query.

I admit that I haven't use multithreading much before .Net 4.5, but with the new `async/await` functionality I decided to give it a try. I started experimenting with it and all seems fine, but I wasn't able to find a solution for my "problem" anywhere on the web.

So everyone explain how `await` can be used with the newly transformed methods of the .Net platform (e.g. `WriteAsync()`, `ReadAsync()` etc...), but what if I wanted to use it for my own methods? For example, lets say that I am performing an extremely expensive calculation and want all of my 4 cores working on it. I would have something similar to this:

```
async Task DoLotsOfWork<T>(T[] data, int start, int end)
{
    //Do very expensive work
}
```

But since I don't have an `await` keyword there, the method is just treated as a synchronous one. I would like to call it 4 times from outside so that it can run on all of my cores, while I display something sensible  to the user(e.g. "Please wait..."). The only solution that I was able to figure out was to add a `await Task.Yield();` in the start of the method. Something like this:

```
async Task DoLotsOfWork<T>(T[] data, int start, int end)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    //Do very expensive work
}
```

In that case, the method would behave as I would expect it to. But is there a better solution for this? I feel that it should be easier/more sensible than writing exactly that line of code. I understand that I can create a `Task/Thread` object and call the `Start()` method, but that requires even more work. I just thought that with the new async/await functionality this sort of thing would be easier.

Comment: The new async / await pattern does not offer multithreading. It just offers cleaner code for handling operations that block your current thread.

Comment: The keywords do not mean, "use all my cores". They just tell the compiler and the runtime that an operation can be performed on a sperate thread. If there a 4 operations that may be run concurrently they might be run on 4 different cores.

Comment: You want to take a look at this [asynchrony vs concurrency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods), async await DOES NOT help with multithreading. Its useful for even single cored machines.

Comment: Ok. So in other words - don't use async/await for multithreding. I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: Its not that don't use, but rather you cannot use it for that. It was not meant to do that, so it cannot do it.

Comment: You can most certainly use await in conjunction with multi-threaded code, you just need some mechanism to start running code in another thread, once you've done that through some other means, `async/await` can help you manage them more effectively.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So to start with you'll need a method that does the very expensive work synchronously:

```
public void DoLotsOfWork<T>(T[] data, int start, int end) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);//placeholder for real work
}
```

Then we can use `Task.Run` to start multiple instances of this work in a threadpool thread.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>DoLotsOfWork(data, start, end));
}
```

Then we can do a non-blocking wait until all of them are done:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the `Parallel` class, which *is* designed for parallel processing.

Comment: @StephenCleary the issue there is that the parallel methods block until the results are done, so you end up needing to throw the `Parallel.For` or `Foreach` into a `Task.Run` if you are currently in, say, a UI context and can't block until the tasks complete.

Comment: @Servy: True. But the benefit of `Parallel` is it will automatically partition work to make the best use of your available cores. As you said, you can wrap it in `Task.Run` to get a `Task` representing parallel work.

Comment: If from one of the `Task.Run(() => myFunction());` I have a myFunction() returning some value, how do I handle it?

Comment: @codeln Have a `List<Task<T>>` and store the result of `await Task.Whenall` in a variable.