# Is it mandatory to await SaveChangesAsync() on asyncronous EF?

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

My scenary is something like this

```
//a lot of database dependant processing

db.SaveChangesAsync(); //asynchronouly saving database changes

//a lot of ANOTHER long term database INDEPENDANT stuff
```

since await db.SaveChangesAsync() waits until all changes are made to database (could take some time) and I don't want to wait, but in paralell I want to make the other log term stuff below WHILE SaveChanges is saving changes, why should I use await? If I dont use await I receive the worning in the image below. 
[image]

Comment: I don't think you understand what `await` is actually doing here. If you don't await it, th emethod might exit before it's actually done it's job. Also `await` doesn't mean that it waits for the method to complete before moving on to the next line.

Comment: I think I was mixing two different concepts: paralellism and asynchrony. I was reading this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods to figure out how I could gain some responsiveness in a windows forms application. But I still can't anderstand how I could gain some performance in an asp.net MVC application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is quite clear - you're starting an asynchronous task, but you have no mechanism for being notified when it's complete. What if you *do* need to know when it's done, later? Before returning from your method, or at a point where you need to be sure that the data is synchronized with the DB?

`await`ing the operation is one way to ensure that, but as you say, you don't want to stop the independent processing while the data is saved. `await` is for asynchrony, not for parallelism.

Additionally, `await`ing the Save task ensures that you catch any exceptions that are thrown by the DB. When you simply release the task, any exceptions are lost - at best, you can handle `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` to handle unobserved tasks that throw exceptions, but a much simpler way is to simply *observe* the task.

One way to observe the task is `await`, as you know. Another is to simply save the `Task` object that `SaveChangesAsync` returns in a variable. This will allow you to `await` (or `Wait()`) on that Task later, catch its exceptions (either by try/catching the `await` call or by attaching a `ContinueWith` to the Task) and will let the compiler rest easy knowing you're not abandoning the task to its fate:

```
//a lot of database dependant processing
var dbSaveTask = db.SaveChangesAsync(); //asynchronouly saving database changes
//a lot of ANOTHER long term database INDEPENDANT stuff
// now, before assuming the DB is up to date, ensure the TAsk is complete. 
await dbSaveTask;
// now do something Db-dependent!
```

Comment: `await` also lets you detect database update errors; without it, you would never know if the updates fail.

Comment: Well, you could attach a Continuation to the task and examine the AggregateException that is returned, I presume.

Comment: (which is what `await` does)
The point I meant to make was that if the op *discards* the returned task, then there's no knowledge of failures.

Comment: Important to clarify, I agree. I'll edit that into the answer

Comment: I commented my question above. I was confused about how async really works.