# Add items to a list in a foreach loop asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach

I have a loop that retrieves objects from a 3rd party API (hence why I have to ask for each object one at a time) and adds them to a list that I then return out of my procedure. It currently does these sequentially but I'd like the loop to be asynchronous to improve performance.

The basic code looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<ResponseObject<MyClass>>> GetMyClass(string[] references)
    {
        var responseObject = new ResponseObject<MyClass>();
        var responseObjects = new List<ResponseObject<MyClass>>();

            foreach (var reference in references)
            {
                responseObject = await GetExternalData(reference);
                responseObjects.Add(responseObject);
            }

        return responseObjects;
    }
```

The method I call is defined as this:

```
public async Task<ResponseObject<MyClass>> GetExternalData(string reference)
```

How do I need to change this to get it to turn the same list of ReponseObjects, having loaded them in parallel rather than sequentially? Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: A bit of of naming, as title of your question is misleading. In your code sample, code is _already_ asynchronous - control leaves your method on await keyword and comes back in future when task completes. Further in your post you correctly call what you want a _parallelisation_. Asynchronous != Parallel.

Comment: @GrayCat actually parallelization is also a wrong term for this case. The OP wants to achieve [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods), to have multiple operations running concurrently in other words. Unless the `GetExternalData` method is CPU-bound, which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this with a `.Select`:

```
public async Task<List<ResponseObject<MyClass>>> GetMyClass(string[] references)
{
    var responseObject = new ResponseObject<MyClass>();
    var responseObjects = new ConcurrentBag<ResponseObject<MyClass>>();

    var tasks = references.Select(async item => 
    {
        var responseObject = await GetExternalData(item);
        responseObjects.Add(responseObject);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return responseObjects.ToList();
}
```

There's also an [AsyncEnumerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator) NuGet package which includes a `ParallelForEachAsync` that works very similarly to `Parallel.ForEach`. I would recommend using that approach if `references` can be quite a few objects. As written above, this will spawn off as many tasks as there are `references`. Using the `ParallelForEachAsync` you can control the degree of parallelism to avoid too many requests, it would look like this:

```
public async Task<List<ResponseObject<MyClass>>> GetMyClass(string[] references)
{
    var responseObject = new ResponseObject<MyClass>();
    var responseObjects = new ConcurrentBag<ResponseObject<MyClass>>();

    await references.ParallelForEachAsync(async item =>
    {
        var responseObject = await GetExternalData(item);
        responseObjects.Add(responseObject);   
    }, maxDegreeOfParallelism: 8);

    return responseObjects.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This absolutely needs to be using a thread-safe data structure like ConcurrentBag. Alternatively return the tasks from GetExternalData in the select, await all the tasks and then synchronously add the task results to the list.

Comment: @ScottyD0nt Yes, you're right, I changed it to be concurrent for thread safety.

Comment: It would be easier to *return* the objects from the `Select` lambda and then you get a collection of them from `WhenAll`.

Comment: That's given me exactly what I wanted - thanks! I had missed the bit about using a ConcurrentBag in my feeble attempts to do it initially.