# PyTorch mutiprocessing: Do I need to use Lock() when accessing a shared model?

Tags: pytorch, python-multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning

I have some questions about using the `torch.multiprocessing` module. Let’s say I have a `torch.nn.Module` called `model` and I call `model.share_memory()` on it.

What happens if two threads call the `forward()`, i.e. `model(input)` at the same time? Is it safe? Or should I use Lock mechanisms to be sure that `model` is not accessed at the same time by multiple threads?
Similarly, what happens if two or more threads have an optimizer working on `model.parameters()` and they call `optimizer.step()` at the same time?

I ask these questions because I often see the `optimizer.step()` being called on shared models without lock mechanisms (i.e. in RL implementations of A3C or ACER) and I wonder if it is a safe thing to do.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. Please, take a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for taking care of it

Comment: I would also suggest that you put your main **specific** question in the title, to make it more descriptive of your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be safe, [since they are running asynchronously not in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844774/7347631). Quoting from the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#asynchronous-multiprocess-training-e-g-hogwild),

> Using torch.multiprocessing, it is possible to train a model
> **asynchronously**, with parameters either shared all the time, or being
> **periodically synchronized**. In the first case, we recommend sending
> over the whole model object, while in the latter, we advise to only
> send the state_dict().