# Asynchronous method does not work well in Console application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, parallel-processing, console-application

I am using the following code and want to test the parallel programming, but there are some problems.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoParallelApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** Main Method Start ***");
            Operation();
            Console.WriteLine("*** Main Method End ***");
        }
        static void Operation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method Start ***");
            var task1 = Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method End ***");
        }

        static async Task<int> Delay(int ms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms}(ms) Delay");
            await Task.Delay(ms);
            Console.WriteLine($"End {ms}(ms) Delay");
            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

```
*** Main Method Start ***
*** Operation Method Start
*** Start 5000(ms) Delay
*** Operation Method End ***
*** Main Method End ***
```

But I think it should be like this one:

```
*** Main Method Start ***
*** Operation Method Start ***
Start 5000(ms) Delay
*** Operation Method End ***
*** Main Method End ***
End 5000(ms) Delay
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: parallel or just async?

Comment: async is also parallel, Isn't it?

Comment: With await you are waiting for Task.Delay(ms) to end

Comment: So how should I make a delay?

Comment: Javad here are some explanations of the terms: [What is the difference between concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program finishes before the `Wait` and terminates (including the "wait" method). You need to await the task returned by `Delay` somewhere. To have desired output you can do it like that, for example (using C# 7.1 `async Main` [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)):

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Main Method Start ***");
        var t = Operation();
        Console.WriteLine("*** Main Method End ***");
        await t;
    }
    static Task Operation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method Start ***");
         var task1 = Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method End ***");
         return task1 ;
    }

    static async Task<int> Delay(int ms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start {ms}(ms) Delay");
        await Task.Delay(ms);
        Console.WriteLine($"End {ms}(ms) Delay");
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the Delay:

```
static async Task Operation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method Start ***");
    var task1 = await Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("*** Operation Method End ***");
}
```

And call Operation with await as well, in your case as the `main` method is not `asyncable` you can do it this way:

```
Task.Run(() => Operation()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: This will not help since `Operation` is `void`  and not awaited.