# How many threads can execute in parallel in a single CPU or across all CPUs?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am aware about general concept of async tasks and threads.

I want to ask:

How many threads can run in a single CPU in parallel?

How many threads can run across all CPUs in parallel?

Comment: FYI, async tasks don't always take a thread: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: For example a Ryzen 7-5800X having 8 physical cores and 16 logical cores thanks to the technologies of which I forgot the name can execute 16 *real threads* in parallel at the level of the processor itself at the same time as you can see on the graph of the Windows Task Manager or other.

Answer (score -1):

Each CPU-core can run only one thread at any given moment. So for example in a quad-core machine, the maximum number of threads that can run [in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods) is 4.