# How to utilize parallelism to "add" two Dictionaries together faster?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I am fairly new to C#. I would like to "add" two Dictionaries together using parallelism.

Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new()
{
    { "a",  1 },
    { "b",  2 },
    { "c",  3 },
    //...
};

Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new()
{
    { "a",  1 },
    { "b",  2 },
    { "c",  3 },
    //...
};
```

Result of `dict1 + dict2`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict3 = new()
{
    { "a",  2 },
    { "b",  4 },
    { "c",  6 },
    //...
};
```

I currently have a solution where I wrap a `Dictionary<string, int>` in my `Modifier` class:

```
public class Modifier
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> modifier = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void Add(string key, int value){
        modifier.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key){
        return modifier.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public int this[string key]{
        get => modifier[key];
        set => modifier[key] = value;
    }

    public static Modifier operator +(Modifier a, Modifier b){
        foreach (string key in b.modifier.Keys){
            if (a.ContainsKey(key)){
                a[key] += b[key];
            } else {
                a.Add(key, b[key]);
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

To add, I do `Modifier result = a + b` (where `a` and `b` are `Modifier` objects). However, for my application, I will be doing many of these "additions" on large dictionaries and am afraid it will not scale well.

I am not very familiar with C# parallel programming. I thought about splitting the keys into equal sub-groups and performing the addition one each group, but I am not quite sure how to implement it, or even if it is optimal.

**What is the most efficient way to do this addition?**

Comment: why would you want to do it async?

Comment: @pm100 The application will have very large dictionaries and will perform many "addition" operations, I would like to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: By *"asynchronously"* you probably mean *"in parallel"*. You can check out the definitions here: [What is the difference between concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods)

Comment: Async programming isn't about efficient.  If anything Async programming is less efficient because it requires the use of state machines every time you invoke an async method.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-performance-characteristics-of-async-methods/ If you're ALSO wanting to ensure that your user interface doesn't hang while you're adding these together... then maybe Async is what you want.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for the clarification. I have edited my post for clarity.

Comment: @Kevon I am creating a video game using Unity, so there is definitely user input. I do not want the FPS suffer too much doing these additions.

Comment: `am afraid it will not scale well` How much time have you spent trying to solve a problem you're not sure exists? Don't prematurely optimize - just implement it the best you can and optimize later when you can prove it's an issue.

Comment: Also it sounds like you're assuming a solution here. You're asking how to optimize this solution you thought of without telling us the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @branpham  Since UI is an element, then yes... Async might be for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/... essentially, write a method on your class that returns a Task instead of void, and then in the UI thread you can use await it so that it is not blocking.  You MAY still want to run that in parallel to get better performance though.  If you think this is the right path, I can try to put up some sample code as an answer

Comment: As a side-note, the `operator +(Modifier a, Modifier b)` is mutating the `a` modifier instead of returning a new modifier. This is counterintuitive. In general when you add two things together you expect to get the result of the addition as a third thing, not to mutate the first of the two things. I can't think of any built-in .NET type that has a `+` operator that behaves like this.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are absolutely correct. I have just tested it. I will update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallelism is unlikely to yield impressive performance improvements in this case. Actually it's more likely to make your operators slower than faster, on top of being tricky to implement and easy to get it wrong. My suggestion is to focus at optimizing the single-thread performance of your operators. Here is a suggestion:

```
public static Modifier operator +(Modifier a, Modifier b)
{
    foreach ((string key, int value) in b.modifier)
    {
        ref int valueRef = ref CollectionsMarshal
            .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(a.modifier, key, out bool exists);
        valueRef = exists ? valueRef + value : value;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Only one string hashing is performed in each iteration of the `foreach` loop. This alone will probably give you a performance boost of 100% or more. You can read about the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) method in the docs (it is available from .NET 6 and later). Be careful, it's a low-level method.

You might be able to improve the performance even further by initializing the dictionaries with a specialized `IEqualityComparer<string>`, provided that you have specific knowledge about the inner patterns of the actual strings that will be used as keys. You might find interesting a related API proposal on GitHub: [Provide optimized read-only collections](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67209).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the optimization. Your post was very informative.

Comment: This is what I was about to start saying in a comment but, better.